# android eclipse plugin can't find valid paths

Tags: android

I just installed the latest galileo eclipse release.  I added the
latest adt plugin and configured it to use my android sdk (r4).
Unfortunately, the eclipse plugin is wiggin out.  for some reason, it
can't find(execute?) the android tools.  I get this error on the
eclipse project:

> Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at 
>   ~/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt

but here is the output of ls:

```
ls -al ~/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 solid solid 3416259 2009-12-18 21:02 /home/solid/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt
```

When I try running the program directly, I see the following:

```
~/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt
bash: /home/solid/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt: No such file or directory
```

I just unzipped the sdk and installed the platforms and `ls`'d it so I know it is there.

I have tried recreating the project from the command line (which
works) but when I import it into eclipse I get the same error.

BTW this is linux amd 64

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something is very wrong here. These two lines contradict themselves:

```
$ ls -al ~/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 solid solid 3416259 2009-12-18 21:02 /home/solid/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt 

$ ~/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt
bash: /home/solid/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-1.6/tools/aapt: No such file or directory
```

The file just can't exist one instant, then cease to exist in the next.

I don't think this is caused by running on amd64, since I'd suspect that would give you a different, more descriptive error. That being said, make sure you have the ia32-libs installed:

```
# Assuming you're on Ubuntu
$ apt-get install ia32-libs
```

My only advice would be to try completely deleting your SDK installation and re-installing it from scratch.