# Command line "Android update sdk" on headless Linux

Tags: android

How can I update/install the Android SDK platforms on a headless Linux server?

All I got was the following error:

It seems like the action "update sdk" is actually not supported.

```
~/android-sdk-linux_86/tools$ ./android --verbose update sdk
No command line parameters provided, launching UI.
See 'android --help' for operations from the command line.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterWindowImpl.open(UpdaterWindowImpl.java:93)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.UpdaterWindow.open(UpdaterWindow.java:110)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showMainWindow(Main.java:281)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:251)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:92)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

---

<sub>The question was asked when headless update wasn't supported. As of 2012, it is now possible to do just a `android update sdk --no-ui`.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automate the android sdk installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation)

Comment: Duplicate: *[Is there a way to automate the Android SDK installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation)*. The [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/command-line-android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux/4682349#4682349) is just a link to one of the answers to that question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Updating Android SDK headless and automatically is described in Stack Overflow question *[Is there a way to automate the Android SDK installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation/4682241#4682241)*.

Comment: Huge note: `android update sdk --no-ui` will install ALL platforms, from eclair to marshmallow. To prevent that you need to use the --filter parameter such as `android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1,2` for just the platform tools and sdk tools, like adb and fastboot. For the full list of filters run `android list sdk` http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line

Answer (score 78):

You can use the `--no-ui` option:

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

If you'd like to automate it, you could accept all licenses by using the `expect` tool with this hack (the `--accept-license` option is currently not fully integrated in the `android` tool):

```
expect -c '
set timeout -1;
spawn android - update sdk --no-ui;
expect {
    "Do you accept the license" { exp_send "y\r" ; exp_continue }
    eof
}
'
```

Comment: to accept the license automatically, next version will add a `--accept-license` flag. Meanwhile you can `echo "y" | android update sdk --no--ui`

Comment: @Snicolas do you have a source for that? The references I saw make it appear to require a specific license number as parameter, and likely be for internal use. Would love to be wrong...

Comment: You can find an example here on github : https://github.com/embarkmobile/android-sdk-installer/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: @Snicolas Didn't try echo, but I was prompted twice, so it definitely wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same problem. I found a workaround though.

The first one is a cop-out: Download the platforms on a headed system and simply copy the platform subdirectories into your Android *sdk/platforms* directory.

If, like me, you don't have immediate access to another headed Android development environment, you can go to Google's SDK archives and download one of the other SDK's that included the platforms. This way means that you can only develop for Android 1.1 and 1.5 though.

The download to get for Linux systems is their Android 1.5 r3. Of course, Google's SDK download pages aren't [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)-friendly, so I had to get the direct link from another GUI system.

```
wget http://dl.google.com/android/archives/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.5_r3.zip
```

Then it's simply a matter of unzipping the archive, and moving the platform subdirectories to your newer SDK platform directory.

```
android create avd -t 3 -p path/to/avd/dir -n "name"
```

This creates an [AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) for the 1.5 platform with your specified name and directory. Note that the *avd* directory shouldn't exist. If you want to overwrite, add `--force` to the command.

Getting this far has a platform installed and creates an AVD. Unfortunately, trying to build failed at this point for me, because I run a 64-bit server, and Google only releases 32-bit tools.

I found a solution for this in the accepted answer of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943746/android-eclipse-plugin-cant-find-valid-paths) and used `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` to enable the ability to run the 32-bit tools.

Then you should be able to use the `android` tool on the CLI to either convert an [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) project (for 1.5 or lower) to have an [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) build system, or you can have it create a new project for you to start working on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works but you need the GUI libraries installed and you need your [DISPLAY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#True_environment_variables) environment variable set to what X server you want it to display.

I have it working now on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5.4 and had to use the "Server - GUI" verse "Server" install option.  Then I just use "ssh -X" from the system where I want it to display.

Comment: can you provide a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3):

I just created a small command line tool that does the update in any environment (GUI or non-GUI). Didn't have the chance to test it extensively, but as far as I can tell it does what it should.

The command line tool updates a pre-installed base Android SDK with all currently available platforms, add-ons, extras, docs, samples and tools. This should be enough for a build server (I need this for my Hudson CI installation with Maven).

Please go here for more details:

http://code.google.com/p/android-sdk-tool

Answer (score 0):

I had to analyze it using `strace -f -v -s1024 -o/tmp/android.log ./android`. I found the needed libs were being automatically created, and found, under /tmp/swtlib-64/. However, I still got the above error. Digging further into /tmp/android.log, I found `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` was *not* found. So after `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0`, I could run the android installer graphically using `ssh -X` to the headless server.