# How to keep current with SDK updates?

Tags: android, eclipse

Do I need to periodically open the SDK Manager in Eclipse to check for updates to google's Android code, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to manually open SDK Manager and pull down the updates you want.  You can "automate" the update process via the command line though (see: [Is there a way to automate the android sdk installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation))