# How to build Qt5 for Android?

Tags: android, qt5

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I would like to put the server to use building Qt5 for the Android ARMv6 platform. How does one go about doing this on a headless server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The steps necessary for compiling Qt5 for Android on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS are described below. For the sake of convenience, I will assume that all of the commands below are run in the directory `/opt/qt5-android`. You will need to adjust the paths accordingly if this is not the case.

1. First you will need to make sure the appropriate packages are installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-6-jdk
   ```
2. Grab the latest Android SDK:

   ```
   wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.1-linux.tgz
   tar -xf android-sdk_r21.1-linux.tgz
   ```
3. The SDK doesn't ship with any platforms, so you will need to grab them:

   ```
   android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui
   ```
4. Grab the latest version of the NDK:

   **32-bit (i686):**

   ```
   wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86.tar.bz2
   tar -xf android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86.tar.bz2
   ```

   **64-bit (amd64):**

   ```
   wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   tar -xf android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   ```
5. Now clone the following Git repository:

   ```
   git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
   cd qt5
   perl init-repository --no-webkit
   ```
6. We're almost there. Now we need to `configure` and `make` Qt5:

   ```
   ./configure \
       -developer-build \
       -xplatform android-g++ \
       -nomake tests \
       -nomake examples \
       -android-ndk /opt/qt5-android/android-ndk-r8e \
       -android-sdk /opt/qt5-android/android-sdk-linux \
       -skip qttools \
       -skip qttranslations \
       -skip qtwebkit \
       -skip qtserialport \
       -skip qtwebkit-examples-and-demos
   make
   ```

And that's it! You should now end up with a Qt5 build for Android.

---

**References:**

- [Building Qt5 for Android](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding)
- [Is there a way to automate the android sdk installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation/4682241#4682241)

Answer (score 5):

I don't mean to respond to another answer with an answer but this is my first post :-( and I think that that prevents me from posting this in a comment.
(so consider it a citation of said answer, not a reply to it)
Nathan's own answer above didn't work exactly for me.

My configure line looked more like so:

```
./configure \
-developer-build -platform linux-g++-64 \
-xplatform android-g++ \
-nomake tests \
-nomake examples \
-android-ndk /opt/qt5-android/android-ndk-r8e \
-android-sdk /opt/qt5-android/android-sdk-linux \
-skip qttools \
-skip qttranslations \
-skip qtwebkit \
-skip qtserialport \
-android-ndk-host linux-x86_64
```

Here's why:

- `-skip qtwebkit-examples-and-demos` caused an error in configure... It didn't like that I was skipping something that couldn't be built anyway (sorry, I lost the exact error message)
- `-android-ndk-host linux-x86_64` stopped configure from aborting with "
  `Can not detect the android host. Please use -android-ndk-host option to specify one`"
- `-platform linux-g++-64` is me being paranoid about whether or not configure will add the `-m64` flag or whatever when working its magic for me

Other than this difference, Nathan's procedure seemed to work like a charm. My local environment building now (thanks for the tips, Mr Osman :-)