# Android Maven Could not find tool 'aapt'

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

i was trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.gdgankara.org/2012/11/01/step-by-step-android-development-with-maven/

but after setting up the environment, and create a project, at the "run as\maven install" step i got this:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tutorial 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ tutorial ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.889s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 18 00:32:12 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project tutorial: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources failed: Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I've tried lot of times, but with no luck.
I have Eclipse Juno on Windows7 64 bit, APK Tool installed and Maven 3.0.5.

It seems a well known problem for maven staff:

https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=104

but it should be solved from ages...

My Environment User variables:

```
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.0.5

ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk
```

My Environment System variable:

```
Path=......;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platforms;%M2_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\android-4.2.2
```

Does anybody know how to workout this trap?

thanks!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem when using latest ADT from google and trying to compile the bootstrap android platform.

The latest r17 build separate out `aapt` to build-tools folder. Hence it is maven-android-plugin cannot support it.

See issue discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=377&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20OpSys%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary).

Tried and working:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/lib lib
ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/aidl aidl
```

Some installations may be structured using the API version:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/lib lib
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aidl aidl
```

**Keep in mind that this is fixed in the latest version (>3.5.3) of the Android Maven Plugin, as other answers point out.**

Comment: oh i see..it's clear. i thought i was safe adding the "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\android-4.2.2" statement to environment path...anyways i beg you pardon but, is there a way to add those commands in windows?
May i workout this appending lib,aapt and aidl to environment Path variable?

Comment: I've also saw that there's a fix for the new SDK structure:
https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/205
I didn't understand where i'm supposed to put that new class...

Comment: i had the suspect that windows users like me, even with mklink, can't append soft link to ANDROID_HOME and so are doomed...

Comment: bah,,,i copied aapt.exe to folder platform-tools...and it worked,,
 
quite an horrible solution...

Comment: On my latest install, android-4.2.2 was "17.0.0". Not sure if that's a recent change for everyone, or just for a Mac user installing the standalone SDK.

Comment: Yes mine was 17.0.0 as well.  I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Here is the windows version:

    mklink aapt.exe ..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe
    mklink /D lib ..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\lib
    mklink aidl.exe ..\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aidl.exe

Comment: Keep in mind that this is fixed in the latest version (>3.5.3) of the Android Maven Plugin, as other answers point out.

Comment: Of course on android 4.3 it's:

**cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.3/aapt aapt

ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.3/lib lib

ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.3/aidl aidl**

Comment: For me this problem was originated because Ive updated GCC on Linux and forgot to update GCC 32bit / Multilib.

Answer (score 21):

Update:

This has been resolved since [Android Maven Plugin v3.6.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/maven-android-developers/f6OXWC5lRsA/1H7sRqIF7_QJ).  For now you will only need these symlinks if you use IntelliJ v12.x.  IntelliJ v13 EAP+ should work out of the box.

Original answer:

This has been fixed and will be released with Android Maven Plugin v3.5.4.  See the github pull request:

[Upgraded AndroidSdk to use path and platform utilities from sdklib](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/207)

You can try validating the snapshot build which contains the fix by adding the following to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</plugin>
...
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>oss.sonatype.org-jayway-snapshots</id>
    <name>Jayway OpenSource SNAPSHOTs on Sonatype.org</name>
    <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/jayway-snapshots/</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Please provide feedback on the developer group:

[New snapshot for 3.5.4 available](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/maven-android-developers/2Qit97rVDeA/Wd67L7wQadEJ)

Comment: version 3.5.3 does not work. I ran into the same issue running 3.5.3 I have not tried the 3.5.4 or 3.6.0 yet.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Windows, the symbolic linking can be done using [`mklink`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) command.

```
D:\>cd "Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"

D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk>cd platform-tools

D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>mklink aapt.exe ..\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe
symbolic link created for aapt.exe <<===>> ..\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe

D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>mklink aidl.exe ..\build-tools\17.0.0\aidl.exe
symbolic link created for aidl.exe <<===>> ..\build-tools\17.0.0\aidl.exe

D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>mklink /d lib ..\build-tools\17.0.0\lib
symbolic link created for lib <<===>> ..\build-tools\17.0.0\lib
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me (for now). Now we'll just have to wait for the android maven plugin to support the new structure.

Answer (score 0):

I get stuck with the same problem. Finally i managed to resolve the issue after two hours. To make it simple and resolve the issue in 5 minutes i listed the steps below

**Step 1** - In Eclipse update your **Android Maven Plugin** to 0.4.3.2013 using the beta release link
`http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/master/`

**Step 2**

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <sdk>
                <platform>17</platform>
            </sdk> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

It will solve the following issues

`"No Android Platform Version/API Level has been configured"`

`Could not find tool 'aapt'`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar problems.

Solved by following steps :

1) Upgrade maven to 3.1.1
2) Use android-maven-plugin 3.6.1 pr greater [I used 3.8.0]
3) Use maven-dependency-plugin 2.8

If you want to build against latest Android SDK [ex : 4.3], follow following additional steps -
4) Install the local copy of android.jar using command mvn install:installFile ..
5) Set 18

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using macOS 10.14 and in my case:
I download Android packaging tool from [AAPT](https://androidaapt.com/) and then copied all the files into 
`$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$SDK/tools/`

**DON'T REMIND CHANGE $SDK WITH YOUR REAL NAME SDK FOR INSTANCE android-29**