# Targeting a specific system-image version using the 'android' command line utility?

Tags: android, macos, scripting, android-emulator

Background: I've created a headless OSX workstation-bootstrapping script, which installs `android-sdk` via [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and sets up a Chef-solo environment. I mention this because any sensible tool/predictably-named remotely-hosted file is on the table for solutions.

My problem: 
I need the Android API 16 system-image and I can't seem to find the right flags/package namespace using the `android` CLI utility.  I was able to install the 4.1.2/API 16 SDK Platform using `android update sdk -u --filter android-16`, but I still need the system image for emulation.

`android update sdk -u --filter system-image` installs API 17/4.2.2.

I'd like to avoid doing a grep-based solution over running `android list sdk`, not that it seems to be an option anyway (`android list sdk | grep 'API 16'` doesn't bear fruit).

I've looked at the XML file that the `android` CLI utility calls to enumerate its package list (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml) and found a link to the file that I believe I want , http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sysimg_x86-16_r01.zip, but I'm not thrilled at the parse XML + go around the existing utility option.

I've seen [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation) and while it was helpful, it doesn't completely cover what I'm attempting to do.

Am I missing a flag or using the wrong package name?  If so, what documentation source did I miss?  How could I solve this for myself in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now use individual package identifiers.  For your case, one of:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter sys-img-x86-android-16 --all
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-16 --all
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter sys-img-mips-android-16 --all
```

The `--all` is necessary because without it, `android` will ignore packages it considers old even if they match the filter.

You can find a list of the identifiers with `android list sdk --extended --all`

Comment: Good to know; thanks for taking the time to add an answer.  I've accepted your answer to help future viewers.  I'll leave my answer below in case this option gets reverted, fails to work, or someone is on an old version of android tools.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly hackish solution, but here's how it can be done -- order matters in the running of the CLI commands.

Get the Android API 16, 4.1.2 SDK Platform:

`echo -ne 'y' | android update sdk -u --filter android-16`

Without API 17 installed, immediately install the system image.  Ostensibly, this will follow whichever the most recent version of SDK platform tools happen to respond on the box:

`echo -ne 'y' | android update sdk -u --filter system-image`

If you want API 17, install android-17 and then run the system-image install command.