# Build (not develop) your android app .apk (gradle build) on server?

Tags: android, python, jenkins, gradle

I'm trying to build(not develop) an android application on server. I've the whole native android code on the server, which I need to build according to some modification done on the server.

I've been looking all over the internet but couldn't find any detailed solution. All I got to know was I might need Jenkins or some CI tool (which I think is time consuming as I'll need to get them installed on server and then all the android dependencies).

Initial idea was to build the .apk file via some python script which contains all the gradle commands in it.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Android apps can be built easily on a system that doesn't have any Android tools installed by applying the [Android SDK Manager plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin) for Gradle to your project.

When running `./gradlew assembleDebug` (or whatever task), then Gradle will be installed and then all Android dependencies, including the SDK tools, build tools, platform versions and other dependencies will be installed automatically.

You can run this simply on the command line yourself, or automate to run after every commits to source control easily with [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) (it's easy to install on a wide range of operating systems).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Stand-alone SDK tools and suitable SDK packages to your server to build Android software.

When you have all installed and good, you can build APK with gradle , e.g.
(Linux and Mac)

```
./gradlew assemble
```

Comment: Can this task be automated via some python script or some tools?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, there seems to be some work done on it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation