# Automatically accept all SDK licences

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Since gradle android plugins [2.2-alpha4](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system):

> Gradle will attempt to download missing SDK packages that a project
> depends on

Which is amazingly cool and was know to be a [JakeWharton project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin).

But, to download the SDK library you need to: accept the license agreements or gradle tells you:

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK
> components: [Android SDK Build-Tools 24, Android SDK Platform 24].
> Before building your project, you need to accept the license
> agreements and complete the installation of the missing components
> using the Android Studio SDK Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to
> transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to
> http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

And this is a problem because I would love to install all sdk dependencies while doing a `gradle build`.

I am looking for a solution to automatically accept all licenses. Maybe a gradle script ?
Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: You can also pop an `echo y |` in front of that command to auto accept the licence. Useful when running on a headless CI box :)

Comment: I had to do `~/.android/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.0,android-25,extra-android-m2repository` because the `android` tool was localized to my home

Comment: sdkmanager --licenses no longer works. I used --upgrade, ignored the errors and this sorted the license problems.

Comment: sdkmanager --licenses in Android\tools\bin folder worked for me!

Comment: I've used this command for CI environment build script with small adjustment. I've added --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_PATH. Problem was that licenses were accepted and not saved to Android SDK root folder.
Final command: yes | sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_PATH (without sudo)

Comment: Be sure to have set `$ANDROID_SDK_PATH` to the actual root path where you've installed the SDK (i.e.: `/opt/android-sdk`), or just put the path directly (i.e.: `yes | sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=/opt/android-sdk`)

Comment: ```yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses
``` this throws an ```Error: Unknown argument --licenses```

@nsvir

Comment: In ubuntu docker, this worked for me: `RUN sh -c ' printf "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n" | ./sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: @gmc that comment is quite important actually, if you work through cmd it's very likely you set ANDROID_HOME, so it doesn't work whatever else you do

Comment: I haven't seen "sdkmanager --licenses" work on any SDK since ~2017 - FYI
Use "sdkmanager --update" instead

Comment: I get ye sno se reconoce como comando interno

Comment: Where do you run yes | sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_PATH because yes is not a command.

Comment: for window open cmd and change dir to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin and execute " sdkmanager --licenses"

Comment: errors when executing sdkmanager --licenses with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)

Comment: **Note for Linux users**, in my case there was a permission issue, so I used `sudo`, only to realize that after accepting the licenses, they still showed as not accepted under `user`. To solve this, precede the `sdkmanager --licenses` with `sudo chmod a+w $ANDROID_HOME/licenses`

Answer (score 548, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372165/1155507) should be the accepted answer as its easy and upto date

---

AndroidSDK can finally accept licenses.

Go to `Android\sdk\tools\bin`

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

EDIT:

as pointed out in the comments by @MoOx, on macOS, you can do

`yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

as pointed out in the comments by @pho, @mikebridge and @ Noitidart on Windows, you can do

`cmd.exe /C"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses"`

be sure to install java before

Comment: On Widows I had to go to Run then `C:\Users\x1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android` then it popped open a GUI and then install missing then click "Accept Liscenses" in new dialog that pops.

Comment: This is not working for linux. There is no sdkmanager file under the tools/bin dir or somewhere else. Can you please help?

Comment: On macOS, you can do `yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: How can I accept licenses automatically from gradle wrapper?

Comment: On mac via CLI on the path `/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`, execute: `yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: If automating this process (maybe using Travis?), you need to update sdkmanager first by running: `sdkmanager --update`

Comment: Finally, as of which version was this feature introduced?

Comment: This worked great in my `Dockerfile` where I had to accept all licenses during installation of certain packages in SDK manager: `RUN yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.2" "platform-tools"`

Comment: upvote to @Noitidart for the path, but it didn't work, I had to run C:\Users\x1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses
from the command prompt and hit "y" + Enter to the prompts

Comment: Thanks @gangt for upvote and sharing the better path!

Comment: Where do I find sdkmanager? It's not in my bin folder for the "Android Studio and SDK tools" that I downloaded.

Comment: Mine is at `C:\Users\UserName\sdk-tools-windows-4333796
\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat`.

Comment: I have to change the location to 
{ yes | sudo /opt/android/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
}

Comment: on windows, if you happen to have GitBash installed. you can run `yes | C:\Users\x1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses` there

Comment: I had issues with this and couldn't run the sdkmanager, if you have an issue with it complaining about some Java.xml file, be sure you're using Java8 as I had Java11 set as my global version

Comment: None of the command line stuff worked for me on Windows, but going to Tools -> SDK and downloading another SDK prompts you to accept licenses.

Comment: Good god android development is garbage.
I started out a couple of years ago using one of *their* template examples, and every time I go back to it, there's a new version of android studio, and it takes hours to get that project - which was working fine - working again...

Comment: "sdkmanager --licenses" hasn't worked in years and people still post it as a solution and people still upvote it. What am I missing? Y'all using old AF AndroidSDKs?

Comment: One license was nicely accepted by command `echo y| "%ANDROID_SDK_PATH%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "ndk-bundle"` on Windows.
It *must* be without space between `y` and `|`

Comment: On Mac while running the above command if you face issue like "zsh command not found sdkmanager Mac"  it means you have not installed JDK. So please first install JDK and then run the above command. All licences will be accepted. Now you can proceed with your work like again run the project and you won't get any issue.

Comment: `--licences` is not part of the SDK any longer!

Comment: I needed to follow this link before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994924/sdkmanager-command-not-found-after-installing-android-sdk

Comment: I needed to add `sudo` prefix, then it worked. Otherwise it said "licenses accepted" but when I checked again they were not actually accepted. With `sudo` it became permanent.

Comment: This actually doesn't work, because you're not downloading sdk's, so you still get halted.

Comment: Lubuntu : I had to apt install sdkmanager and then type "sudo sdkmanager --licenses" TWICE (saying "y" the first time).

Comment: Have a look at this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828925/gradle-you-have-not-accepted-license-agreements-android-sdk/78029332#78029332

Answer (score 299):

I was getting this error:

```
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.
```

So, I went to Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. Then I installed Google Play Licensing Library. It solved the problem.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to disagree with @AminPinjari and Cedric, this didn't make a darn bit of difference for me.

Comment: You dont have to reinstall everything - it is sufficient to run `android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: Thank you, it is working on Windows with Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 on 2021-08-02

Comment: I don't understand why this is needed with a fresh install of AS but I'm happy that this answer exists! I just installed this and then did a gradle sync and all was great.

Comment: I found and used this solution for my issues while I was using a Windows PC. I shifted to Mac, found the same problem and the same solution fixed my issue yet again. This is the best answer as of 2021.

Comment: This worked easily. But all the same building software is getting complicated.

Comment: It's nice that it works, but why???? why does it work? why is it needed?

Comment: And what is the equivalent on the command line?

Comment: can someone point out how can we do it using command line (debian)?

Answer (score 185):

I have encountered this with the `alpha5` preview.

Jake Wharton pointed out to me that you can currently use

```
mkdir -p "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses"
echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-license"
echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
```

to recreate the current `$ANDROID_HOME/license` folder on you machine. This would have the same result as the process outlined in the link of the error msg (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/license).

The hashes are sha1s of the licence text, which I imagine will be periodically updated, so this code will only work for so long :)

> And install it manually, but it is the gradle's new feature purpose to do it.

I was surprised at first that this didnt work out of the box, even when I had accepted the licenses for the named components via the `android` tool, but it was pointed out to me its the SDK manager inside AS that creates the `/licenses` folder.

I guess that official tools would not want to skip this step for legal reasons.

Rereading the release notes it states

> SDK auto-download: Gradle will attempt to download missing SDK packages that a project depends on.

Which does not mean it will work if you have not installed the android tools yet and have already accepted the latest license(s).

EDIT: Saying that, it still does not work on my test gubuntu box until I link the SDK up to AS. CI works fine though - not sure what the difference is...

Comment: There is a small glitch in sdkDownload feature regarding some of the components, e.g., support-v4. It *will* update the components but gradle won't see update until next invocation. One workaround to exec gradle twice, once to throw away: *gradle dependencies || true* -- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212309

Comment: you can use `mkdir -p` instead of `|| true`.

Comment: It works thank you for this glitch, good to know. To check if your SDK path is defined as expected : 
   echo $ANDROID_SDK

Comment: In my environment ANDROID_SDK is not defined, but it works with ANDROID_HOME

Comment: This fails for Android SDk 26.

Comment: Looks like another UID is needed for platform and build-tools: `d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e`. `8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55` still works for Google Repository and Android Support Repository.

Comment: @Paul, Can you please add a code snippet which adds the new key. For me, the build is failing at the line "Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip"

Comment: @stack_ved: I've just added another `echo`: `echo -e "\nd56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" >> "${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license"`. But I think your problem hides somewhere else.

Comment: true, the problem is with the new way of installing dependencies may be. SOmehtin like the accepted answer. Or what @nsvir has mentioned above. Any idea?

Comment: Turned out for me what @Paul is suggesting worked. But i am looking forward to fix it for good. Thanks Paul!

Comment: any option to prevent gradle android plugin from automatic download of  missing components?

Comment: if you want to get this sha `n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55` you should run in your terminal **sdkmanager --licenses**  at the bin folder of the path of your sdk , then accept it , then open the license file you accepted

Answer (score 147):

For the newest Android Studio (2.3) the best way to update/accept all licenses is to run:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME
tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

you might still need to copy the licence files to other locations based on your setup.

Comment: This looks like the best way to go and it works on all platforms too, just run `tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: If you got old sdk manager --licenses wont work. It is necessary to copy tools folder to another location then use --sdk_root= and point it to your sdk folder, then you would be able to update tools to newer version.

Comment: can we pipe `yes` into this command somehow for automated build systems? You won't always have interactive console access to these machines, so pressing `y` on keyboard physically won't work.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me how to implement this solution? Got to add this line in build.sh?

Comment: it worked for me but i had to do ``cd $ANDROID_HOME`` before executing this command

Comment: Worked for me, but maybe you should add `cd $ANDROID_HOME` just to be more clear where to execute this, anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: I have android studion 3.0.1 I have updated all the sdk tools but I still see license error, I do try to run the command but I got this error:
-bash: tools/bin/sdkmanager: No such file or directory

Comment: Not a valid answer to the question. This still needs manual input and thus it is not automatic as asked.

Answer (score 61):

For the new `sdkmanager` utility:

`yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;24.0.3"`

There's a bit of a delay between yesses, so the command could hang with the license showing for a while, but it doesn't require human intervention.

Comment: In my install debian9 I only have a sdkmanager.jar: android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar and # java -jar /android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar
Error: The tools directory property is not set, please make sure you are executing android

Comment: This is based on the assumption that you downloaded the SDK tools as an archive from Google and unpacked them into $ANDROID_HOME

Comment: This seems the most `up-to-date` answer. It seems `--licenses` does not exist anymore.   Note: to see list of possible versions that can be provided: `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up using `yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses || true` in my CI.

Comment: es | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3" -> changing the version worked for me . Thanks !

Answer (score 46):

If you are using Jenkins, you can use the following bash script as first step in the build process:

```
(while sleep 3; do echo "y"; done) | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk -u
```

This will of course install ALL available updates, but it will save you some time if you can spare the disk space. The sleep is to avoid the broken readline in the installation program, since "yes" does not work properly in this case.

EDIT: You also need to add the "Install Android project prerequisites" plugin in the build step to get the correct $ANDROID_HOME if you are using the built-in SDK manager.

Comment: I add your line of code before "cordova platform add android" in my jenkins build which is running on Ubuntu but still getting following error : BUILD FAILED in 7s
Error: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa_global_php/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:

Comment: [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
 Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Comment: "The sleep is to avoid the broken readline in the installation program" <- What does that mean?

Comment: That android tool is deprecated

Answer (score 36):

We found same issue building the project on Jenkins. With `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'`, we must accept licenses before building. In our case, we needed to run:

`yes | sdkmanager --update` that accepts licenses for the sdkmanager itself, and then

`yes | sdkmanager --licenses` that accepts new licenses not previously accepted

Remember: run these commans with the same user that `jenkins` does. In our Debian, the Jenkins user is just `jenkins`. In other words: doing it as `root` will create the accepted licenses as `root`, so Jenkins will not be able to read them.

By the way, we found `sdkmanager` at `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/bin`. If yours is not there, find it with `find / -name "sdkmanager"`

Comment: this one solved the issue in my case too (build tools 26.0.x), with Jenkins in Docker. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not include the "automatically" part of the question.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for your comment! I've updated the question to match with last version feature to automatically accept all licenses without human intervention.

Comment: @Maruf install the Android SDK and add it to the path :·)

Answer (score 36):

this solved my error

```
echo yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.2"
```

Comment: To save a few characters, `yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.2"` does the same thing.

Answer (score 32):

Unfortunately the way as OP originally solved it does not always work. 
If you find from the error message what is your builds current *build-tools **version***. It could be that it is a higher version of build-tools that is missing. In that case you need to manually start SDK Manager and add the build-tools and accept license.

Per OP instructions, it look as follows.

`$ ./gradlew build`

```
 
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.2].

...
BUILD FAILED
```

---

> **NOTE: 2017-04-16**
>
> The `android` tool has now been deprecated in favor of the new `sdkmanager`. Please see Joe Lawson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42009817/1147688) and subsequent posts from March (2017) and onward.

Then adjust you command as follows:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-24.0.2,android-24,extra-android-m2repository
```

```
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
...
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-24.0.2'
-------------------------------
License id: android-sdk-license-xxxxxxxx
Used by: 
 - SDK Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 2
  - Android Support Repository, revision 39
-------------------------------

...

November 20, 2015
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-xxxxxxxx' [y/n]: y

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading SDK Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 2
  Installing SDK Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 2
    Installed SDK Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 296%)
  Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 39
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 39
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 3999%)
  Done. 2 packages installed.
```

Running this again, still do not make Gradle happy. So manual acceptance is the only solution until someone come up with something better. (Please do!)

Comment: `android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-24.0.2,android-24,extra-android-m2repository` running this via command prompt with admin right fixed the error. I was unable to install [phonegap plugin manager](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

Answer (score 24):

The `android` tool is deprecated and you should use the `sdkmanager` instead. `sdkmanager` also writes the licenses file when you first accept it. The license changes depending on which SDK you are using so even though the command

```
echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-license"
```

works on some systems. It won't work on all. Some SDK installs expect to license file to end without a newline in the file so try adding a `-n` to the echo command.

```
echo -n -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-license"
```

If that isn't working you can try using the base64 encoding instead.

So to discover my license:

```
$> rm ${ANDROID_HOME}/
$> unzip tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME}
$> ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;default;x86_64"
```

It'll prompt you to accept the license. After accepting it'll copy it to `${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license`. To ensure you always get exactly what is written use `base64`.

```
$> base64 ${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license
Cjg5MzNiYWQxNjFhZjQxNzhiMTE4NWQxYTM3ZmJmNDFlYTUyNjljNTU=
```

Then you can use `base64 -d` recreate the file exactly.

```
$> echo Cjg5MzNiYWQxNjFhZjQxNzhiMTE4NWQxYTM3ZmJmNDFlYTUyNjljNTU= | base64 -d > ${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license
```

You can verify if the file written is what is expected by running a sha1sum on it.

```
$> sha1sum ${ANDROID_HOME}/licenses/android-sdk-license
da6b80c9c47b41c0bf7032938e7137a58a3dc249
```

Answer (score 19):

if you run `yes | sdkmanager --licenses`, then we print content of `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license`,

we will get this

```
# cat $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license

8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55

d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e
```

For GitLab CI, to accept Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 licenses, you need to run this

```
before_script:
  - mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/licenses
  - echo "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license
  - echo "d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" >> $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license
```

Comment: You're second echo is going to the same `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license` is this intended? ie. appending

Comment: @RyanR, yes, the second echo is appending, `Android SDK Build-Tools 26.02` added a new license sha1 string

Comment: I'm using bitbucket pipelines, but the concept seems to be the same as with GitLab CI. Your answer helped me understand the whole process better. Thanks!

Comment: @Ridcully I'm also using Bitbucket Pipelines and found myself here when we upgraded to `Build-Tools 26.0.2` and our build broke. My end solution was to simply do `yes | sdkmanager --licenses`. No `echo`s needed and this is future proof.

Comment: @Ryan You mean I can just add 'yes | sdkmanager --licenses' to the pipeline.yml? That would be great!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. sdkmanager says unknown argument --licenses... perhaps a newer version would be required?

Comment: I'm using the latest android sdk https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip. Here's my `Dockerfile`: https://git.io/vdS5k

Comment: (Using SDK 27) since my CI is Windows-based, I did the following: copied and checked-in the whole `%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses` folder into the git repo as `./exported-licenses`, and then in the build file I put as follows: `xcopy exported-licenses %ANDROID_HOME%\licenses /s/h/e/k/f/c/y/i`

Comment: This worked for my non-production build, but production complains I haven't accepted all licenses. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 17):

Note that for anyone coming to this question currently, build-tools-24.0.2 is (I think) now considered obsolete, so you'll get:

```
 Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-24.0.2'
```

when running the various commands that have been suggested to install them.

The solution is to add `--all`:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-24.0.2"
```

Also if you're on 32bit linux, *everything* [after build tools 23.0.1 is 64bit only](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866), so will not run. 32bit users are stuck on 23.0.1, the only way to get a later build tools is to switch to 64bit.

Comment: Yeah, build-tools was just bumped to `25.0.1`.

Comment: Your solution was the only thing I could find to work on a headless ubuntu 16 machine for build-tools-25 and gradle 4

Answer (score 15):

If you use `tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` you still need to have a human interaction. I have the problem using my gitlab CI. This is my solution:

```bash
wget --quiet --output-document=tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
unzip -qq tools.zip
echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools"
echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.2"
echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
```

`echo y` will say yes if there is any question, but you need to make one line per installe package

Comment: Still quite relevant after several months. Thank you. You saved my day :)

Comment: This was helpful for me, also using GitLab

Answer (score 15):

You can also just execute:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

And in Windows, execute:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Answer (score 14):

Ok FOR ANYONE HAVING THIS ISSUE AS OF 2018. The above answers did NOT work for me at all. What DID work was opening Android SDK - clicking the DOWNLOAD button on the tool bar and selecting the appropriate packages. After they finish downloading, it will let you accept the license agreement.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio for Windows, the solution is as follows:

Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Appearance & Behaviour` -> `System Settings` -> `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools` -> check `Google Play Licensing Library`  -> Click `Apply`, and then `Ok`

After the installation, build your application. It will work.

Comment: It worked! Welcome to the community :-)

Answer (score 11):

For an error message about SDK api number 25:

`android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-25.0.1,android-25,extra-android-m2repository`

Answer (score 9):

## Note: This is only for Mac users

I had same issue but *none of the answers posted helped* since there was no `tools` folder present in `Library/Android/sdk.` (I'm using Android 3.6.3 on Mac OS 10.14.4)

[image: error screenshot]

Below steps helped me to overcome licensing problem error:

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. Press `cmd + shift + A`. This opens `Actions` pop-up window.
3. Search for `SDK Manager` and hit enter to open.
4. This opens pop-up for `Android SDK`. Select some other version of Android apart from already installed one. (In my case Android 10.0 was already installed so I selected Android 9.0)
5. Then select `Apply` button. This will install corresponding SDK.

[image: Solution]

6. Now run your app it **should work without any exception.**

[image: success screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

For those having issues with the command line SDK, the reason it won't find the licenses you have accepted is because they have have been written to a different location than `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses` which is where they need to be.

I found the easiest solution was to accept the licenses like this:

`$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME`

Note: This assumes you've set `ANDROID_HOME` to point to wherever your sdk is installed.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by creating a public git repo with the accepted license files.  Then I use `wget` to fetch these licenses on any machine I need into a **[sdk-dir]/licenses** directory before running **./gradlew** to build my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't tell me how to solve the problem. Can you share how you obtained the "license files"?

Comment: @FrederickNord Licenses are obtained from your **$ANDROID_HOME/sdk/licenses** on your computer.

Answer (score 7):

I went to Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. Then I installed Google Play Licensing Library. It solved the problem.

Comment: For MacOS, this works

Comment: And for Monterey the accepted answer appears *not* to work, so this one is required!

Answer (score 6):

`cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
yes | ./sdkmanager --update`

or

`yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update`

Comment: "Automatically"

Answer (score 6):

for windows, open cmd and enter into `bin` directory by running command:

```
cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

then run `sdkmanager --licenses` command, it asks to accept licenses.

Comment: Thanks this is what I did

Comment: I get `Error: Unknown argument --licenses`

Answer (score 5):

In Windows PowerShell, you can do

```
for($i=0;$i -lt 30;$i++) { $response += "y`n"}; $response | sdkmanager --licenses
```

This is much more flexible and requires zero manual intervention.  The 30 number is arbitrary, should be enough to cover the number of license acceptances, but can be increased if needed

Comment: Great answer, this worked for me still in 2023. Running above command allowed me to accept all licenses, then I was able to use sdkmanager to install all the packages I needed without issue.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution on Windows, to have a real silent and automatic install:

On Windows, the following syntax doesn't work:

```
echo y | sdkmanager --licenses
```

It seems the "y" aren't correctly sent to the java program called in the batch.

The workaround is to create a file file-y.txt with several "y", one by line, and to use

```
call sdkmanager --licenses < file-y.txt
```

This will create the needed files in the licenses directory. The problem is probably related to the use of BufferedReader in Java

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the above command on windows 10 machine
but the solution was to use the SDKMANAGER to check and accept licenses buy installing missing versions

[image]

Comment: None of the CMD commands worked for me, only this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is my Docker setup. 
You can follow from a plain Linux environment.

Note that `yes |` and `--licenses --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}` clauses. 
It seems `sdkmanager --update` reverts agreements, so `yes |` is appeared twice.

```
FROM openjdk:8
# Install dev-essential(gnumake)
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y build-essential
# Set ENV
ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=28 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3 \
    GRADLE_VERSION=4.10.3 \
    NDK_VERSION=r16b
# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}
# Install Android Build Tool and Libraries
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools" --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}
# Install Gradle
RUN wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-all.zip
RUN mkdir /opt/gradle
RUN unzip gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-all.zip -d /opt/gradle
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/opt/gradle/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin
# Install NDK
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-${NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN mkdir /opt/ndk-bundle
RUN unzip android-ndk-${NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip -d /opt/ndk-bundle
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/opt/ndk-bundle

RUN mkdir /application
WORKDIR /application
```

Comment: "It seems sdkmanager --update reverts agreements, so yes | is appeared twice."


Wow, you're right. This is very frustrating but good find.

Answer (score 4):

> Download the SDK manager from this [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip). Then unzip and use the following command in terminal.

```
!tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/usr/lib/android-sdk --licenses <<< $'y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n'
```

Comment: That `<<< $'y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n'` 
part did the trick on my side. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 3):

Copy the entire licenses/ directory and paste it into the Android SDK home directory on the machine where you wish to build your projects.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

this resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error while using Cordova.

The problem was due to the fact that I installed Android Sdk through Android Studio and through `apt` with `apt install android-sdk adb`. And Cordova was calling the files installed through `apt` instead of the files in my home directory.

It worked once I changed the path to SDK in bash:

```
# Change path
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk/"
echo "Android home = $ANDROID_HOME"
# Accept licenses
eval "${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses"
# Run Cordova
cordova build android
```

Then I removed the system files that weren't used anymore: `apt remove android-sdk adb`.

Answer (score 3):

You can accept all the license by executing the following command:

```
 sdkmanager --licenses
```

This will prompt you through each licenses you haven't accepted yet and you can just enter `y` to accept each of them.

Comment: "Automatically"

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Flutter** just run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And accept all the licenses needed.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced two errors while Build my project on Android Studio:

1. `License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted. (while Build my project in Android Studio 4.1)`
2. `exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounderror javax/xml/bind/annotation/xmlschema (while running SDK manager to accept license)`

For me, it was a java version problem. I have installed JDK instead of java. **TO SOLVE THE ISSUE**, I did the following steps.

**For Windows:**

**Step1**: Download and install the latest JAVA version from https://www.java.com/en/download/

**Step2**:  Search for "View advanced system settings" in the start menu button (windows icon)

**Step3**: Click on "Environment Variables"

**Step4**: under "System variables" click on "New", now set "`Variable name: JAVA_HOME`" and "`Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271`" (add latest installed java path here). Then "OK", "OK", and "OK".

**Step5**: open cmd as an administrator and type the following commands:

1. `cd C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin` (*change username here)
2. `sdkmanager --licenses`

Press "y" for all questions.

**Step6**: Restart your Android Studio again.

DONE.

Let me know if anyone having a problem while following the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

As of **July 2019**, the easiest method is to use: `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in the command prompt.

It proceeds to display the unaccepted T&C of SDKs one by one and you're given option to choose 'y/n'. Choose y for all.

Alternately, when you run `flutter doctor`, it will run Android toolchain diagnostics which displays how many licenses are not yet accepted, and suggests you to run it with the --android-licenses flag.

Comment: I was going to downvote but I am going to make a comment. This is only valid if you have flutter or you are developing with flutter, which is not the case of the OP. sdkmanager is the right way as it is generic enough as it covers everyone that has the Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

This path has been changed in the recent versions. 
`./sdkmanager` is now in `/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` and then just do

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Why the in the living eff does Android make this so hard? It's a license. It should be a checkbox.

Comment: @MattWest because your environment variables aren't configured correctly. You can use the UI if you're just doing it locally

Answer (score 2):

If your "tools" folder is missing on MacOS, then you can do the following-

1. Use command+shift+A to open actions in Android Studio (the shortcut may vary)
2. Search for "SDK Manager"
3. Go to "SDK Tools"
4. Check `Android SDK Platform Tools` and click apply.

The tools folder should now appear.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the package with the licence fail in the `android sdk manager` tab.
At reinstall, a prompt will ask you to accept the licence

[image: android sdk manager]

Answer (score 1):

I run

```
#react-native run-android
```

from terminal and met that problem. 
For manually, go to Android Studio -> Android SDK -> SDK Platform
Click Show Packages Detail and check :

```
+ Google APIs
+ Android SDK Platform 23
+ Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
+ Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
```

When install packages, check accept license => can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX, navigate to the `sdk/tools/bin`

Then run `./sdkmanager --licenses`, and accept all the licenses.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 opening `cmd` with administrator privileges and then typing `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\` and then `sdkmanager --update` worked for me. After that I just had to press "y" twice in order to accept the licenses.

Comment: You still have to interact. That's the issue of the OP's question. It should be silent upgrades. THis won't with a pipeline

Answer (score 1):

In windows go to command prompt and type the following commands:

```
cd C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
sdkmanager --licenses
```

This will generate the licences keep pressing "y" to accept all licences.

Comment: `Error: Unknown argument --licenses`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I though that these answers didn't help then I figured out that my environment variables wasn't correct, although I was able to do `sdkmanager` command anywhere, so make sure that the environment variable is set correctly:

1. In the environment variables define a new variable with
   `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` as a name and give it a value of where the
   sdktools are located eg.: `C:\Android\sdk\`
2. Edit your path to add the created variable to be
   `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools\bin\` restart you cmd.
3. Run the command that where mentioned in the answers: 
   `sdkmanager --licenses`
4. Install the desired packages using `sdkmanager "packageName"`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if you didn't install any SDK, Android Studio also shown "you haven't accept the license"...Such deceiving message, normal people would assume it implied SDK were already installed but anyway. In the Studio's SDK manager, you can just manually select the missing sdk to download and install and it handles license too. You just need to restart the Android Studio.

Here is [a YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g789PvvW4qo) showing your where SDK manager is.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, with `sdkmanager` in your PATH and [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) installed and configured, the following one-liner should work with every default distro (in fact I can't think of a counterexample):

```
wsl --exec yes "y" | sdkmanager --licenses
```

If that's not enough, you might want to look at [this script](https://github.com/mataha/android-accept-licenses) (disclaimer: it's mine).

Answer (score 1):

I did successfully accept the license with the command

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
```

HOWEVER, the license was not saved anywhere. I would run the above command many times to accept all licenses but **kept asking for them again**. So the solution was to simply add `sudo` to the command...

```
sudo sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
```

Thie successfully generated multiple license files under `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running inside a Docker container or creating a Docker image, to avoid docker executor failed running code 141, you should use the following:

```
RUN (yes "" 2>/dev/null || true) | sdkmanager --licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

I navigate to:

```
/usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
```

and I typed in terminal:

```
echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > $ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-license"
```

With root permission.
And it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

FOR REACT NATIVE APPs:

If you are having this problem for a React Native app, in addition to above mentioned steps, make sure you have the local.properties file in the android directory(AppName/android) of your app which points to your 'sdk' directory:

```
sdk.dir=/PATH_TO_SDK/
```

Comment: Setting your android_home variable properly works for react native apps as well. Personally, I set it in my IDE run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error of license not accepted...trying to set up android environment to run a React-native app in android emulator for API level 23.

I did the following:

Based on the link https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#download-with-gradle

Verified if the license got downloaded via the Android studio 3.1.3's SDK manager.

Set up ANDROID_HOME as C:\\Android\Sdk

(it was installed in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)

The error got resolved after retrying the build in a new command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many the possible solutions mentioned by members from the community I just found there might have been different problems overtime so most of the solutions are outdated.

Currently, and as [**I posted in the Travis community**](https://travis-ci.community/t/accept-license-for-android-build-tools-27-0-3-bug/549), Travis should be accepting all the licenses by default, but it kept complaining about not accepting the licenses 27.0.3 which shouldn't happen.

Adding:

```
before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

should fix the problem, we we would be able to even use an a 3.+ version of Android Gradle Tools without needing to even declare what version of build-tools we are using:

```
android:
  components:
    # Use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-${ANDROID_API}
    # - build-tools-28.0.3    # WE DONT NEED THIS ANYMORE FROM AGP 3.+

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-${ANDROID_API}
```

**This works as October 29th, 2018. Travis might make changes in the future so good luck with that!**

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a half day to looking for solution for **Bitbucket Pipelines**

If you are using **Bitbucket Pipelines** and you have the issue with accepting all SDK licences, try to use this code in your .yml file:

```
image: mingc/android-build-box:latest

pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      script:
        - chmod +x gradlew
        - ./gradlew assemble
```

It should works.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but all above mentioned solutions didn't worked for me and finally this single line would accept all android licences.

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses && sdkmanager --update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I solved it by opening Android Studio. The fact was that Android Build Tools 26.0.2 wasn't installed. An error came to warn me about it, I installed it and sync it with project. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is `yes | sdkmanager --licenses > /dev/null`, and everything was accepted, and no huge output on the console or travis log or wherever. It also works like `yes | sdkmanager "tools" > /dev/null` for example.

Answer (score 0):

please mind your sdk location, I change the default folder, so i cant find sdkmanager in " ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/"....

Answer (score 0):

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Build-Tools 24, Android SDK Platform 24]. Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Uninstall and Reinstall the Android SDK Platform 24 and then the License agreements will appear, Accept the agreements and the problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

In window this problem can be solved as:
Open CMD in window
run this command in CMD

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

then enter y for accepting each licenses.
the CMD will show you each license one by one which you have to accept by entering y in CMD prompt.
It solved my problem. I hope this will also work for you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this because I can't use the UI. It's for pipelines in Azure. (Windows) none of the answers worked for me, but the @moobyfr posting with file-y.txt pointed me in the right direction

This works on the fresh install. You don't need to use Android Studio at all or any UI.

1. Create C:\AndroidTest
2. Create ENV variable called ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS with path from #1
3. Create ENV variable called JAVA_HOME and give it the folder path
4. open up CMD in Admin mode and go to C:\Android
5. curl --output test.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-8092744_latest.zip
6. Use your favorite command line to extract the zip into the same folder
7. Navigate to the bin folder ( cmdline-tools\bin )
8. In this folder, create a file like mentions in another answer. file-y.txt and add a bunch of y's. Basically type y  on each line. I did 20. So you have 20 lines with 1 y on each
9. sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" --sdk_root="C:\AndroidTest\cmdline-tools\bin" < file-y.txt

This will download all the sdk's you need without the need for gradle/AndroidStudio/Xamarin. It's great for pipelines to download entire SDK support on the fly

If you have an issue, you need to type sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root="C:\AndroidTest\cmdline-tools\bin" < file-y.txt
But, I doubt so.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gitlab/GitHub pipeline you can:

```yaml
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "33"
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "30.0.3"
ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_URL: "commandlinetools-mac-8512546_latest.zip"

curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_URL} -s -o 'android-clt.zip';
mkdir -p android-sdk-mobile;
unzip -o -d android-sdk-mobile android-clt.zip;
echo y | android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}";
echo y | android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}";
echo y | android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools "tools";
echo y | android-sdk-mobile/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=android-sdk-mobile --licenses;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 approach that I can found to this problem.

1. Update sdk tools with command window by accepting licence agreement as follows, just change the version according to your need.

   android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.2,android-25,extra-android-m2repository
2. Second approach is copying licence folders to Android root directory. Goto your development machine open Android Studio. Find your sdk location from Project Structure menu. (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk). Under that directory there must be a licence folder. Copy that folder with the content. Paste that folder in your Jenkins server machine (or where you face with this problem) under android sdk root folder. (C:\Users\UserName.jenkins\tools\android-sdk)

Comment: "Automatically"

Answer (score -1):

Finally, this 2 simple steps worked for me on windows 10.

1) Make sure you update your android build tools and api. On your Android Sdk Just click on install packages to install available updates.

2) Start your Android Studio and you'll be prompted to install the reqiured build tools for the already updated api and tools, This will install the build tools properties including the licences and your done.

Comment: "Automatically"

Answer (score -1):

in Windows :
Open Cmd:

go to install path

falow common:
cd D: or C:

go to sdk directory

with cd common

tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Answer (score -1):

**WINDOWS SOLUTION**

- Open Terminal o Windows Power Shell
- Go to Android SDK folder

*Generally this folder can be find in **C:\Users(your-windows-user)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin***

- Begin in "....\Sdk" folder enter to \tools\bin

Finally path *C:\Users(your-windows-user)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin*

- Verify that sdkmanager.bat  is in location using ***ls*** command
- Excute the next command **.\sdkmanager.bat --licenses**
- Then the terminal will show 7 documents, you need put yes In each one

Answer (score -1):

as pointed out in the comments by @MoOx, on macOS, you can do

yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Answer (score -3):

THIS IS A QUICK FIX;
 1. GO TO C:\Users(YOUR USER NAME)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools
 2. DELETE THE PREEXISTING FOLDER OF THE VERSION THAT HAS NO LICENSE.
 3. GO TO ANDROID STUDIO AND MANUALLY INSTALL THE TOOL AGAIN(this will give you an opportunity to accept the license )
........
(problem solved)

Comment: why capital case... which is interpreted as shouting