# Build Android Java app using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: android, azure-pipelines

I tried using Visual Studio Team Services to build Android APK (written in Java, not C# Xamarin or C++ NDK). I got the following build log

```
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4205318Z ##[section]Starting: gradlew build
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4505312Z ==============================================================================
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4505312Z Task         : Gradle
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4505312Z Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4505312Z Version      : 1.112.1
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4515314Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4515314Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720)
2017-02-16T02:31:19.4515314Z ==============================================================================
2017-02-16T02:31:20.6165346Z [command]D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat build
2017-02-16T02:31:21.8411639Z Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
2017-02-16T02:31:25.9737596Z ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
2017-02-16T02:31:25.9747589Z Unzipping C:\java\gradle\user\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\java\gradle\user\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv
2017-02-16T02:32:07.9772393Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:08.2879991Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:08.4469994Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.2.3/builder-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:08.5719992Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.2.3/lint-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:08.7509993Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:08.8739994Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.2.3/gradle-api-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:10.2871101Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.2.3/compilerCommon-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:10.6431344Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:10.7700063Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.4/asm-parent-5.0.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:11.0513091Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.4/asm-commons-5.0.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:13.4730708Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:14.4572303Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.build-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:15.8547107Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:16.2007105Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:16.4807114Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:16.6577110Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/google/1/google-1.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:17.2267111Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.2.3/builder-model-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:17.3917108Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.2.3/builder-test-api-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:17.6177108Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.2.3/sdklib-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:17.7462683Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.2.3/sdk-common-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:17.8886379Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.1134804Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.2.3/manifest-merger-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.2500662Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.2.3/ddmlib-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.4360646Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.11.0/jack-api-0.11.0.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.5470646Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.10.0/jill-api-0.10.0.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.7340649Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/25.2.3/protos-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:18.9600661Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/25.2.3/shared-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:19.0900658Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/25.2.3/tracker-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:19.6190654Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.4/asm-tree-5.0.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:19.8470657Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.2.3/lint-checks-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:20.0450665Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.5.1/ecj-4.5.1.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:20.8222958Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.2.3/baseLibrary-2.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:20.9553671Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:21.2702746Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4-master/4.5.3/antlr4-master-4.5.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:22.4142749Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/25.2.3/layoutlib-api-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:22.5362745Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.2.3/dvlib-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:22.6572746Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.2.3/repository-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:24.0179705Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.2.3/lint-api-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:24.2049701Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.4/asm-analysis-5.0.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:24.4489697Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:24.6109705Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs-parent/1.1/jimfs-parent-1.1.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:25.5489692Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/uast/145.597.4/uast-145.597.4.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:25.6859696Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.2.3/annotations-25.2.3.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:25.7859705Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:26.1099703Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava-parent/18.0/guava-parent-18.0.pom
2017-02-16T02:32:26.2829704Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:26.7219087Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:27.2518013Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.2.3/builder-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:27.4159037Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.2.3/lint-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:27.5361715Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:27.6390625Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.2.3/gradle-api-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:27.8719549Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.2.3/compilerCommon-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.0043901Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.1268954Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.4/asm-commons-5.0.4.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.3768193Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.4948967Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.6277647Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:28.7918069Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:29.2023186Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.2.3/builder-model-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:29.3223185Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.2.3/builder-test-api-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:29.6760350Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.2.3/sdklib-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:29.8460361Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.2.3/sdk-common-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.1190459Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.3840359Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.2.3/manifest-merger-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.5250347Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.2.3/ddmlib-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.6360355Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.11.0/jack-api-0.11.0.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.7480361Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.10.0/jill-api-0.10.0.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:30.9021378Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/25.2.3/protos-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:31.0297224Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/25.2.3/shared-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:31.1538157Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/25.2.3/tracker-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:31.6383951Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.4/asm-tree-5.0.4.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:31.8221754Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.2.3/lint-checks-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:32.2397267Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.5.1/ecj-4.5.1.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:32.3717281Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.2.3/baseLibrary-2.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:32.5977279Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:33.4067869Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/25.2.3/layoutlib-api-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:33.5168381Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.2.3/dvlib-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:33.6819192Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.2.3/repository-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:34.3252403Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.2.3/lint-api-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:34.4322399Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.4/asm-analysis-5.0.4.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:34.6412396Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:35.2142380Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/uast/145.597.4/uast-145.597.4.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:35.3312400Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.2.3/annotations-25.2.3.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:35.7582475Z Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
2017-02-16T02:32:45.3250269Z File C:\Users\buildguest\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.4600170Z Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 in C:\java\androidsdk\android-sdk\licenses
2017-02-16T02:32:45.4600170Z Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 not accepted.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z 
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z 
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z * What went wrong:
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2].
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z 
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z * Try:
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z 
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z BUILD FAILED
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6979984Z 
2017-02-16T02:32:45.6990048Z Total time: 1 mins 24.177 secs
2017-02-16T02:32:46.0717260Z [Error: D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1]
2017-02-16T02:32:46.0797268Z ##[error]Error: D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1
2017-02-16T02:32:46.0817269Z ##[section]Finishing: gradlew build
```

Apparently, the problem is that I **need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.** but I don't know how to do that on VSTS. Is there a detailed instruction on how to set up VSTS to build Android Java project?

By the way, is there a way to prevent a bunch of downloads?

Comment: Try the solution in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941712/android-gradle-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-sdk-license-error

Comment: Do you try the solution is that thread? What's the result?

Comment: @starain-MSFT It does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, you can refer to this thread below:

[Android Gradle build in Visual Studio Team Services sdk license error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941712/android-gradle-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-sdk-license-error)