# Team Services Git: gradlew failed with return code: 1

Tags: java, android, git, tfs, azure-devops

I am new to Team Services and I am using it to develop an Android app and want to use the continuous integration and automatic build by Team Services Git. 
But every time I make a commit,

> the build fails with an error: gradlew failed with return code: 1

I have configured the agent and set up everything. But can't understand what I am doing wrong here. [image]

I didn't understand this [post](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/553) and it didn't even work.

**UPDATE:**

I am uploading the [logs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvOuIgzBSUHMkKxne-IZWxrlDqt6SA) after changing System.debug=true.

Comment: Have you started by understanding how gradle works and how to troubleshoot issues with it?

Comment: Yes.  Somewhat.  But is this a gradle issue? Since Android studio compiles the gradle but Team services cant.

Comment: Do you use Hosted 2017 build agent or private build agent? If you are using private build agent, do you install Android Support Repository 47 on build agent machine? (Check in SDK manager or run `[android sdk path]\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list commmand`)

Comment: Yes since I am using Android studio, I installed a private agent and yes I updated to 48.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Is it possible that a sdk license error? Please check if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941712/android-gradle-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-sdk-license-error?noredirect=1

Comment: I have accepted the licenses. Still no work.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Does it only occur on the specific project? what about other projects? You can try to create a new project to check if that still occurs.

Comment: I have only one project currently. So can’t tell. Will check with others and update.

Comment: Queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the logs.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I have uploaded the logs. Please check it.

Comment: Have you tried adding "android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}" in your build.gradle as the error log indicated?