# How to approve a license the Android SDK Tool in Jenkins

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I build my project the following message:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Platform 24, Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.1].

In the folder "android-sdk-windows" there is neither file nor folder licence.
In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)  it is not clear where to execute the command 
`android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-24.0.0,android-24,extra-android-m2repository`

Answer (score 1):

It mean you didn't install [Android SDK Platform 24, Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.1].

use

```
android list sdk -e
```

find the sdk and install