# Android accept the license agreements of SDK [Google Repository, Android Support Repository]

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

when I tried to build the project

```
 ionic build android
```

or adding this plugin in particular

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

ir return this problem with licence

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" via npm


Installing "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" for android


ANDROID_HOME=/xxx/Android SDK/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Google Repository, Android Support Repository].

  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED


Total time: 7.315 secs


Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-screen-orientation':Error: /XXX/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/XXX/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)


Error: /XXX/platforms/android/gradlew: Command fail
```

Help please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38096225/794088 should help

Comment: Thanks, that post help me find the answer I'm looking for...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution, the licences I'm looking for are

> [Google Repository, Android Support Repository]

to install those I need it to do

```
$ android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository
```

And that worked for me