# Travis-CI Android SDK license problems

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to build my Android project with Travis and currently I'm getting error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK 
components:
[Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1].
```

I don't know how, but yesterday I could solve problem with that:

```
before_install:
    - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

But now it doesn't help me. I will be grateful for any advice.

Here is build URL https://travis-ci.org/madsunrise/luna-mobile/jobs/325034903 and also I put travis.yml below

```
sudo: required

language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8

notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - rudnev.vanya@gmail.com
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache

env:
 global:
 - ANDROID_API=27
 - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=27.0.2

android:
 components:
  - tools
  - tools # Running this twice get's the latest build tools
  - platform-tools
  - android-${ANDROID_API}
  - build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - extra

script:
   - ./gradlew clean test build
```

Comment: A [quick  search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=You+have+not+accepted+the+license+agreements+of+the+following+SDK++components%3A+Android+SDK+Build-Tools) turns up 57 existing questions with nearly the identical message (the only difference being the specific version number). Did none of them help?

Comment: Most of them don't include Travis-CI and I think it's not my case. But I'm still searching.

Comment: The issue is with the Android SDK, not Travis. Read the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
- ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=27.0.2
```

by

```
- ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=27.0.1
```

or add:

```
- echo yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.1"
```

to explicitly install the matching version and accept the license as commented [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071759/1009132)

**Explanation**

Since [Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 (October 2017)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0)

> you no longer need to specify a version for the build tools—the plugin
>   uses the minimum required version by default. So, you can now remove
>   the android.buildToolsVersion property.

You are not specifying a version [here](https://github.com/madsunrise/luna-mobile/blob/develop/app/build.gradle#L9), you are explicitly installing version 27.0.2, and Gradle is downloading version 27.0.1 without accepting the license agreement as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731625/1009132).

Alternatively add `buildToolsVersion 27.0.2` to your [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/madsunrise/luna-mobile/blob/develop/app/build.gradle#L9):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
```

**Note**

Seems that it's possible to automatically accept all the licenses, and `echo` is no longer required:

```
- yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses
```

But I didn't test it, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38096225/1009132) for further information.

> you might still need to copy the licence files to other locations
>   based on your setup.

Comment: Wow, I just added buildToolsVersion "27.0.2" to my app/build.gradle and it works!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your last suggestion under Note gives `The command "yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses" failed and exited with 1 during .`

Comment: I added a link to the note section, I never tried this option, thanks.

Comment: Try to remove `sudo`, some Travis-ci builds doesn't support it based on your configuration. Ivan is using `sudo: required`. Anyway, if you manually specify a build tools version, you don't need this command in your related question.

Comment: just verified that `- yes | sudo sdkmanager --licenses` does not work. The failure message is `Error: Unknown argument --licenses`