# Ionic 2 Build Process Failure

Tags: android, build, sdk, ionic2, licensing

I coded an ionic 2 app and I have tried to run "ionic run android" to build the apk. I keep getting and error. I have tried everything. I came across this question below but as a newbie I truly can for the life of me figure out what I need to do.

[Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences/38381577#38381577)

please help.

ERROR LOOKS LIKE THIS

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.903 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 24].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

-Open your terminal and type the following command. on windows make sure you open your command line as administrator

```
android
```

-Android SDK Manager should open, If not then you need to fix your sdk path or environment variables.

-Next to the Tab Android 7.0 (API 24) select it FYI(You do not need to download everything only SDK Platform)

[image]

-Now you need to download the SDK, Click on `Install Packages....` on the bottom right corner

[image]

-Once clicked a modal should open. First click on `Android SDK License` and make sure it is **highlighted**.

[image]

-You should now be given the option to Accept the License, which you can do by clicking on the radio button on the bottom right corner

[image]

-Once done you can click the `Install` button , It may take a while so go outside and stare at the sun.

-I tend to restart my computer or terminal afterwords which makes sure everyone knows there's a new SDK but its not required.