# Android NDK CI using Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to build an NDK Android project using Bitbucket Pipelines continuous integration using `ndk-build` (not the newer `CMAKE`). But I am getting the following error when calling `./gradlew assembleDebug`:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/ndk-build: 144: /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/ndk-build: file: not found
:sensorylib:ndkBuild
make: Entering directory '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sensorylib/src/main'
/bin/sh: 1: file: not found
make: execvp: /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/extract_manifest.py: Permission denied
make: execvp: /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/extract_manifest.py: Permission denied
[armeabi] Install        : libSensoryVoiceJNI.so => libs/armeabi/libSensoryVoiceJNI.so
/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk:797: recipe for target 'libs/armeabi/libSensoryVoiceJNI.so' failed
make: Leaving directory '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sensorylib/src/main'
make: /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: Command not found
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libSensoryVoiceJNI.so] Error 127
make: *** Deleting file 'libs/armeabi/libSensoryVoiceJNI.so'
:sensorylib:ndkBuild FAILED

20 actionable tasks: 20 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sensorylib:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 45s
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: java:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          # dependencies
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -y install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
          # environment vars
          - export SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip"
          - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux"
          - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle"
          - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$PATH"
          # download and unzip sdk
          - wget -q $SDK_URL -O android-sdk.zip
          - unzip android-sdk.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME && rm -f android-sdk.zip
          # accept all licences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences
          - mkdir -p "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses"
          - echo -e "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
          - echo -e "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
          # download ndk
          - sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
          # build
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

The `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` path seems correct as I can `ls` the folder and it looks correct. The permission on `ndk-build` also looks correctly set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I was missing `file` in the `apt-get install` dependencies.

Here is the working **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**.

(I also managed to reduce the overall apt-get dependencies)

```
image: java:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          # dependencies
          - apt-get update && apt-get -y install file build-essential
          # environment vars
          - export SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip"
          - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux"
          - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle"
          - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$PATH"
          # download and unzip sdk
          - wget -q $SDK_URL -O android-sdk.zip && unzip android-sdk.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME && rm -f android-sdk.zip
          # accept all licences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences
          - mkdir -p "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses"
          - echo -e "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
          - echo -e "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
          # download ndk
          - sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
          # build
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to accept these licenses that the error is about?
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-25 Android SDK Platform 25
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: I don't think you need to do those `echo`s anymore into the license files. I believe you just need this line to accept all licenses `yes | sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: I figured it out what was the main problem:
1) so no need to do those echo anymore, thanks @Ryan R
2) the actual problem was the version of the cmake that I was using (3.10.2). Now I downgraded to 3.6.0 and it is working fine.
Nevertheless I should specify that I am using the dockerhub image mingc/android-build-box:latest

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version

```
image: umbrela/android-ndk-builder:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          # build
          - chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Where `umbrela/android-ndk-builder:latest` is

```
FROM java:8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install file build-essential

ENV SDK_URL             https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
ENV ANDROID_HOME        /opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV ANDROID_NDK_HOME    $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
ENV PATH                $ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$PATH

# accept all licences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences
RUN mkdir -p "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses"
RUN echo 8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55 > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license
RUN echo 84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license

RUN ls $ANDROID_HOME/licenses

# download and unzip sdk
RUN mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME \ 
    && wget -q $SDK_URL -O android-sdk.zip \
    && unzip android-sdk.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME \
    && rm -f android-sdk.zip

# download ndk
RUN sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```