# React Native Run Android not accepted license agreement of the following sdk components Android sdk build tools 26

Tags: reactjs, windows-10, react-native, android-sdk-tools

Currently I am working on developing a React Native app where I installed two components:

1) React Native Elements UI Toolkit
2) mastermoo/react-native-action-button for FAB button

Before installing the above components, the app was compiling and running fine on my device but post installation of the above components I was getting couple of errors where I didn't have Android API level up to 26 (Android 8.0) installed and installed all of it overnight.

Post installation of the required APIs, I am getting the following error now which I am unable to solve:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
>   You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1].

Tech Specifications:

1) Operating System: Windows 10 (Really fed-up of Windows, soon buying MacBook Pro)

2) Installed Android APIs - 4.2.2 - 8.0 (API 26)

Would be great if you all could help me solve this issue.

Thank you and best regards.
-Rohit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)

Comment: This has been answered multiple times on this website. Please search for it. Basically, you just need to accept the terms as the same statement is saying.

Comment: @sfratini I tried to do that on Windows via Command Prompt, my SDK is installed at C:\Android\sdk. I cd to C:\Android\sdk\ and the moment I issue SDK_Manager.exe --licenses, the SDK Manager UI loads with all list of installed or to be installed/updated APIs

Comment: Try the bat not the exe

Comment: @sfratini Oh great,didn't know that. So, now I issued the command sdkmanager --licenses and now I’m getting unknown argument --licenses

Comment: @sfratini Solved it finally, checkout my answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Finally after a lot of head banging and hair pulling since last 2 days, I've solved this painful issue which one may face while working on Windows environment. The require steps are:

A) Set proper Environment Variables

1) Under User Variables make sure you have ANDROID_HOME and adb variable Path are set like:

```
ANDROID_HOME C:\Android\sdk

adb C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

2) Under System Variables, make sure you have set these Path variables(my sdk is installed at C:\Android, use yours path as per what and where you have on your system):

```
C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools

C:\Android\sdk\tools

C:\Android\sdk\tools\bin
```

B) Close all open Folders/File Explorers and exit all Command Prompt Terminals

C) Open a command prompt terminal as Administrator and issue the below commands (make sure adb and sdkmanager command are accessible from anywhere without changing directory to the SDK directories):

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.1"
```

I was having build tool license issue so the above command. Nevertheless, Accept the license by typing Y, wait for it to print "done"

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

THEN

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```