# Unable to run flutter demo app gives error

Tags: flutter

Error running Gradle:
Unable to download needed Android SDK components, as the following licenses have not been accepted:
Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2

To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal:
flutter doctor --android-licenses.

On checking with Flutter doctor it gives the error:-

flutter doctor --android-licensesAndroid sdkmanager tool not found (/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Comment: Finally after a lot of efforts and research i got the solution to accept licenses in ubuntu/linux terminal [path to android -sdk]:-Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
 this command prompt us to give the option to accept the licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your sdk tools bin directory

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

Also on Windows it does not work with JDK higher than 1.8

[Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)