# "sdkmanager: command not found" after installing Android SDK

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I installed via `apt-get install android-sdk`.

However, doing a `find / -name sdkmanager` reveals there is no such binary anywhere on the system.

On my Mac, the binary exists in `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`.

However, on the Ubuntu system (the system with the issue), the binary does not exist there:

```
$ ls $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
e2fsck
fsck.ext4
mkfs.ext4
resize2fs
screenshot2
tune2fs
```

Where is the `sdkmanager`?

**Edit:**

Not sure why the above didn't install `sdkmanager`, however, one solution I found was to install manually (instead of via apt-get) by downloading the Linux files at https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads under the "Command line tools only" header.

Comment: did you ever find the answer? i am in same situation

Comment: Can you please share some information on where did you extract the content of the commandlinetools package in relation to your solution? did you use the same directory where the android-sdk was created (i.e.: `/usr/lib/android-sdk/`)?

Answer (score 67):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the binary `sdkmanager` is indeed not included in the apt-package `android-sdk`.

This worked for me:

1. Install `android-sdk` via `apt`, as you described:

```
apt-get install android-sdk
```

2. Set environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` if not done yet. For example:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
```

3. Download and install the command line tools of Android Studio from https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools. You actually don't need the full Android Studio, just the command line tools.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip
unzip commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip -d cmdline-tools
mkdir --parents "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest"
sudo mv cmdline-tools/* "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH
```

By placing it as a subdirectory of `ANDROID_HOME`, you can further omit having to provide argument `--sdk_root` to `sdkmanager` as described here: [Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)

Comment: You need sudo to create the directory

Comment: `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/tools/bin:$PATH` seems to be correct, the `/tools/` segment was missing in your commands

Comment: I also needed to adapt the path in the last command.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 using `apt install sdkmanager`.. `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk` wasnt needed.

Answer (score 14):

Since Ubuntu 22 (Jammy), you can simply install it via :

```
apt install sdkmanager
```

Comment: in my cases, it still says `Android sdkmanager not found` , when running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` ...any idea? thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes, apt-get does not install "tools" directory.

To Download Tools Directory ( which has sdkManager, etc..etc).

There are two ways

1. From Android Studio --> SDK Manager --> Check "Show Obsolete packages" --> Download platform-tools
2. Download Cmd Line tools directory directly from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) and place it inside SDK

Comment: If you're using macOS x you can download it with homebrew
```brew install --cask android-sdk```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually start the Android Studio application installed in your system. [ You can search in the application search bar in ubuntu]
Once the installation is completed, you'll see the locations for your SDK manager and your AVD manager.