# Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, android-build, android-sdk-manager, android-studio-3.6

I use the [new *command line tools* for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools) because the old *sdk-tools* repository of Android isn't available anymore. So I changed my gitlab-ci to load the `commandlintools`. But when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

I already tried executing those commandy by hand, but I get the same error. Also if I run `sdkmanager --version`, the same error occurs.
My gitlab-ci looks like:

```
image: openjdk:9-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "6200805"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  #- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - test

lintDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
```

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Instead of passing the argument `--sdk_root` for each single command execution, let's deep dive into the real cause.

Starting from **Android SDK Command-line Tools 1.0.0 (6200805)**, in contrast to **Android SDK 26.1.1 (4333796)**, the `tools` directory hierarchy has been changed.
Previously it was placed right inside `ANDROID_HOME` (which is deprecated, we will use the term `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` for the rest of the paragraph), now it's still named as `tools` (the only thing you'll get after unpacking the downloaded *commandlinetools* zip file), but differently, you have to place it inside a directory called `cmdline-tools` on your own.  The name `cmdline-tools` comes from its package name, where you can get from listing packages command `sdkmanager --list`, whose outputs include `cmdline-tools;1.0 | 1.0 | Android SDK Command-line Tools`.

Wrapping `tools` directory inside `cmdline-tools` directory would make it work, and help you get rid of the annoying `--sdk_root` argument.  But what about the other parts?

Well, that's all you have to change.  Let me explain more.

- The king - `sdkmanager` lives inside `cmdline-tools/tools/bin`, you'd better set in `PATH` environment variable
- `cmdline-tools` should not be set as `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.  Because later, when updating Android SDK, or installing more packages, the other packages will be placed under `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, but not under `cmdline-tools`.
- The final, complete `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` directory structure should look like below, consist of quite a few sub-directories: `build-tools`, `cmdline-tools`, `emulator`, `licenses`, `patcher`, `platform-tools`, `platforms`, `system-images`.  You can easily point out that `build-tools` and `cmdline-tools` are siblings, all sit inside the parent `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

Let me recap in a simple way:

- Set your preferred `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` (just like before)
- Download and unpack the *commandlinetools* zip file into a directory called `cmdline-tools`, which is inside `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
- Append the directory `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin` to environment variable `PATH`, so that the system knows where to find `sdkmanager`

**!!UPDATE!!**

The behavior has changed again since the build `6858069` (Android SDK Command-line Tools 3.0):

- After unzipping the package, the top-most directory you'll get is `cmdline-tools`.
- Rename the unpacked directory from `cmdline-tools` to `tools`, and place it under `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools`, so now it should look like: `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools`.  And inside it, you should have: `NOTICE.txt  bin  lib  source.properties`.  Actually according to the [official Command-Line Tools doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line#tools-sdk), the tree structure should be `android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/`, but I've checked, using `version` or `tools` makes no difference here.
- For your environment variable `PATH`, I would recommend you to set like this: `PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin`, because after update later, you'll get the latest `sdkmanager` placed under `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`, put it in front will make it higher priority.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Unlike the other answers this keeps the "tools" directory, which is actually what is in the zip file.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have answered my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61429994/13154227) :)

Comment: I followed the instructions here - very helpful - thanks! However, I noticed that after running "sdkmanager --install "build-tools;29.0.3", another "tools" folder was created inside $ANDROID_HOME, besides the already existing "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools". That folder seem to have a few more binaries, so looks like should be the one to be added to the PATH. Did you face this? Using sdkmanager v3.6.0 - downloaded today.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is deprecated. we should be migrating to ANDROID_SDK_ROOT.
source: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar

Comment: At the time of writing, there are 3 different `sdkmanager` binaries after updating.  `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager --version` => `26.1.1`
`$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --version` => `3.6.0`
`$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --version` => `4.0.0`

Comment: Thanks. Renaming the `tools` parent dir to `cmdline-tools` fixed it for me. Can't believe how brittle the Android SDK is however

Comment: I'm quite sure it's intentional - Google wants to make the process as difficult as possible to try to migrate everyone to the huge studio package. It's great that we have Stack Overflow to solve these annoyances.

Comment: I just put the downloaded tools folder in cmdline-tools and then renamed it to latest like $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager... And after running sdkmanager, I don't see other 
unnecessary folders created as described by @JingLi in his comment above like $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/... , $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/..., and everything works perfectly. Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for me but now I have a warning "Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/home/{username}/.android/sdk/cmdline-tools/tools' (Expected '/home/{username}/.android/sdk/tools')"

Comment: @PaulLaffitte that's weird.  Because the `/tools` path is the old one, the new one should be `/cmdline-tools/tools`.  Could you please try an update of your AndroidSDK, maybe the warning will go away as it should have the latest `/cmdline-tools/tools`.

Comment: Guys when using this answer consider that there is ```tools``` folder in ```cmdline-tools``` folder I tried three times before noticing it (and girls)

Comment: @PaulLaffitte, the location should be `/home/{username}/.android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest`

Comment: Has this changed recently? Within the `commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest.zip` (as well as the linux version) archive I downloaded, `sdkmanager` is located at `cmdline-tools\bin\sdkmanager`. Is it necessary to add a `latest` or `tools` folder?

Comment: Okay, after moving the contents of `cmdline-tools` under `cmdline-tools\latest`, `sdkmanager` appears to be working.

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty yes, the behavior of the most recent package 6858069 is changed, I'm working on an update.  But TBH, Google should rather fix it and make the behavior consistent and predictable, instead of we always guess and adapt.

Comment: After a tools update, the latest version has just got put in my <android_sdk_root>\tools\bin, so the above path may need updating?  (This tool is /so/ fragile)

Comment: Yes @Ian, it's changing when you update it.  And the behavior is different, that's why I can't give any certain path here.  It's also mentioned here: https://github.com/thyrlian/AndroidSDK/issues/36

Comment: This has changed again. Every release google changes the structure. See this answer for the latest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413427/94557

Comment: @MattWolfe please read patiently inside the !!UPDATE!! section, it's mentioned that: The behavior has changed again since the build 6858069, after unzipping the package, the top-most directory you'll get is cmdline-tools.  It's not like you've said: For "commandlinetools-linux-7302050_latest.zip" the process was different from earlier approaches. Earlier after unpacking, the top folder was called tools, but now the top folder is called cmdline-tools.

Comment: @JingLi But the structure below cmdline-tools base folder changed between those two releases, but yeah they both had top level comdline-tools. I had to update my CI script again with the 7xxx release.  Every update they've done in the last 3 or 4 releases has required CI changes for me.

Comment: @MattWolfe, I just downloaded two versions: 6858069 & 7302050, and had a careful look.  The tree structures don't vary between them.  7302050 has added a new binary retrace under bin directory.  Some tool's version update under lib/external.  A few new libraries have been added into lib/external: javax.inject, jna, xerces, xml-apis.  That's all, no fundamental change in terms of structure-wise.  Please see the raw output and comparison here: https://gist.github.com/thyrlian/1cf9ec816cbb28a020b6fe4f29168677

Comment: Now apparently ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is deprecated:

"ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, which also points to the SDK installation directory, is deprecated." 

https://developer.android.com/tools/variables#envar

Comment: @SaadFarooq yes it's very confusing.  I suppose the easiest answer is to set both

Answer (score 117):

This appears to be a bug with the way sdkmanager locates the SDK installation folder.

A work-around is to set the flag `--sdk_root`. You can move ANDROID_HOME declaration higher, then use it with the subsequent commands.

```
 - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
 - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --licenses
 - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platform-tools" "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
```

Also, moved blanket license acceptance command to the first command to clean up the `echo y` parts.

Oddly enough if you run `sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "tools"` it will upgrade tools from 3.6.0 to 26.1.1 and sdkmanager no longer has this issue. This update takes time and bandwidth and isn't exactly necessary with the work-around.

Comment: worked fine, now I get an error with ./gradlew assembleDebug, but it seems that this has nothing to do with the sdkmanager anymore. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please give me an example how I can clean up my echo y? I don't get it.

Comment: I've updated the snippet in my original response to clarify removing the `echo y` commands.

Comment: Thank you! Helps a lot!

Comment: the export line and then the `sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "tools"` bit did it for me -- thanks!

Comment: The `-` in the start of the statement are misleading.

Comment: Doing `sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "tools"` leads to errors for me reporting that "tools" folder is already used (as it contains `sdkmanager` itself maybe). ArturS answer, proposing to store sdkmanager in `cmdline-tools/latest` makes everything work perfectly.

Comment: ~I needed to add `yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --licenses || true` because the command kept being detected as failed by gitlab-ci~. Sorry, missed `+o pipefail`

Answer (score 43):

For those who struggled with installing Android Command Line Tools for Appium on Windows 10/x64 just do as following:

1. Download latest Command line tools from android i.e. commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip
2. Unzip the downloaded file
3. Create directory for storing commandline tools somewhere on your disk, with following path included: **android/cmdline-tools/latest** Basically when You unzip this Cmd line tools, just rename **tools** directory to **latest** and make sure You put this **latest**  folder in **android/cmdline-tools** directory somewhere on your disk
4. Create **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable for directory that stores the cmdline tools directory location like:
   **C:\YourLocationWhereYouStoreTheDirectory\android\cmdline-tools\latest**
5. Create new entry in Path environment variable as **%ANDROID_HOME%\bin**

Comment: Where does the need of this "android/cmdline-tools/latest" comes from ? source code ? some doc somewhere ?

Comment: The reason is described under this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460429/android-studio-installs-without-sdkmanager

Comment: In the topic you are referencing, the answer says "export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/darish/development/sdk/android"" no "latest", no "cmdline-tools"

Comment: @Tristan `cmdline-tools` is a must have, however `latest` is not required.  And the path (or name) of `cmdline-tools` comes from Android SDK itself.  You can run this command `sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --list`, where the results includes "cmdline-tools;1.0        | 1.0        | Android SDK Command-line Tools"

Comment: I don't know what logic behind this. But it works :-)

Comment: Perfect, it worked for me too. Just be very careful with the naming of the folders and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 32):

The `sdkmanager` tries to figure out the android-sdk path based in where it's unpacked, without use the environment variables, like `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. But it's get worse, because it have a **hard coded parent folder** named `cmdline-tools` and if you unzip commandlinetools inside a folder with another name, it doesn't work, forcing us to use the parameter `sdk_root` to feed the inside variable correctly.

So, with that in mind we can use the following approach to solve this.

I will assume that we are using Ubuntu OS, so if you aren't, you should adapt some of that instructions.

1. Install Android-SDK.

   ```
    sudo apt install android-sdk
   ```

   After the instalation you will have a folder called android-sdk in /usr/lib
2. Create a folder called cdmline-tools inside the android-sdk folder

   ```
    sudo mkdir /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
   ```
3. Download the Android command line tools zip from here (https://developer.android.com/studio?hl=en-419#downloads)
4. Unpack the file you just downloaded inside /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools

   ```
    sudo unzip /path/for/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip -d /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
   ```
5. Go to you home dir and edit your .profile

   ```
    nano .profile
   ```
6. Create an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable

   ```
    export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
   ```
7. Put the sdkmanager folder in your path

   ```
    export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH
   ```
8. Save and Exit
9. Reload you profile

   ```
    . ~/.profile
   ```
10. Run

    ```
    sdkmanager --version
    ```

You should see the version printed in your terminal.

Comment: it worked like a charm!
thanks again for this complete solution

Comment: I still have the error of "Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee"- Could you explain why? And what should I do to solve this? You dint'd mentioned anything about that. Cheers

Comment: I did not experience this problem, but maybe that answer can help you. [try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287619/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-java-se-ee-while-running-sdkmanager-licenc)

Comment: foolder order and names ... very important!

Comment: I get `android-sdk : Depends: android-sdk-platform-tools (>= 20) but it is not going to be installed` and this has a dependency chain that don't automatically get resolved

Comment: Followed every step. Worked without any issues. Thanks!

Comment: worked like charm. for any one who has issues with package updates .. ```Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.``` check this out [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227439/18-04-installing-packages-using-android-command-line-tools/1227957#1227957]

Answer (score 27):

Downloading the new cmdline-tools from Android Developer website requires the following directory structure to be respected.

[image]

Comment: Why is it required ? where does this come from ? source code ? doc ?

Comment: I setup my CI to use this structure and while it does allow me to run sdkmanager, when my project gets built with gradle it doesn't know how to locate platforms and licenses properly and everything fails.

Comment: @MattWolfe, this happens because some tools only recognize the old SDK Tools ([now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools))

Answer (score 24):

Simple Solution:

1. Open Android Studio Tools Menu,
2. SDK Manager In the window that comes
   up there are inner panels,
3. Choose SDK Tools panel Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools
4. Choose Apply button near the bottom of the window

Comment: Best solution on this page

Comment: Short and precise!

Comment: This worked for me and saved much time!

Answer (score 8):

Mixing responses from Jing Li and caller9, this is my script:

```
variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "6200805"

before_script:
  - apt-get update --yes
  - apt-get install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - export ANDROID_HOME=${PWD}android-home
  - install -d $ANDROID_HOME
  - wget --output-document=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - pushd $ANDROID_HOME
  - unzip -d cmdline-tools cmdline-tools.zip
  - popd
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/
  - sdkmanager --version
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platform-tools"
  - sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}"
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
[...]
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution to use the latest command-line tools following those steps:

1 - Extracting the Command-line tools into a folder with this structure: 
e.g.: `$HOME/Development/android/cmdline-tools/latest` 
(this folder must contain **lib**, **bin**, **notice.txt** and **source.properties**)

2 - Defining **ANDROID_HOME** as an environment variable:

```
ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Development/android/cmdline-tools/latest"
```

3 - Loading it on **PATH**:

```
PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

Comment: Contradictory informations : "latest (this folder must contain lib, bin, ...)", ANDROID_HOME=".../latest" PATH="...$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib

Comment: lib is in tools or in ANDROID_HOME ?

Comment: `cmdline-tools` is a must have, however `latest` is not required.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error. After doing all solutions, i could not fix it. I solved this problem by reading: https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-not-working.844969/

Simplify an answer:

1. Opening `sdkmanager.bat` by notepad++
2. Changing this line from

   ```
   "%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
   ```

   to

   ```
   "%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS% --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME%
   ```

(Note: Adding `--sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME%` at the end

Comment: Thank you, easy and it works! :) But now you should use --sdk_root=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT% instead.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same issue, came here by Google.
According to the [AndroidStudio Archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive), today was the release of 4.1.
I suppose that's no coincidence.

This [completely unrelated guide](https://dev.to/jay_js/setting-up-flutter-without-android-studio-olo) has a hardlink for an older version of the [sdk-tools for linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip).
You can change the url to windows or mac for other OSs. I'll use that as a hotfix for now.

(that was supposed to be a comment not a solution)

Comment: Links not working, I already tried using an old version, but I use new features in my code base so I can't use the old one anymore. So this solution don't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing several useful posts here, and for people wanting a quick snippet, for example to plug in a `Dockerfile`, the following script is working for me:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/android/cmdline-tools/latest \
    && cd /opt/android/cmdline-tools/latest \
    && wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip \
    && bsdtar --strip-components=1 -xvf commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip \
    && yes | bin/sdkmanager --licenses \
    && bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2" "platforms;android-29" \
    && rm commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
```

It just requires `bsdtar` to be installed (it's usually packaged in popular distributions). Android platform/build tools version 29 are installed, and Android sdk root will be then located in `/opt/android`. While this setup works for me without warnings as it is, I have an issue when reinstalling packages already installed, or possibly installing different version of the packages: it clashes with packages already present and create bogus directories in the sdk root, with `-2`, `-3` suffixes. These directories are then ignored, and warnings like `Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location` are printed, so this behavior is definitely not desirable. If you have a fix for that please write it in the comments or, if you are confident enough, just edit the script with the exact fix.

Comment: Nice one, just `bsdtar` doesn't work for me, I use `unzip` instead.

Comment: @Ibrahim.H fill free to share the command line if it's a oneliner and it strips the first directory as well

Comment: I'm using `unzip` without any option, unzip doesn't have that `--strip-components` argument, for those who want to simulate this option can try this:
https://superuser.com/questions/518347/equivalent-to-tars-strip-components-1-in-unzip

Answer (score 5):

Just solved this issue with IDE, looks pretty simple to me. (Actually this duplicate previous answer but with the picture). Just install sdk tools and everything should work.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when downloading the [standalone command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) (`commandlinetools-mac-6200805_latest`) on a new Mac.

Based on all the answers here, I was able to make it work like this

```
# Define ANDROID_HOME, if not defined already
export ANDROID_HOME="~/Library/Android/sdk"

# Create the folder if missing
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME

# Let the tool know that it should use that SDK location. 
sdkmanager --list --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME
```

The docs for the `--sdk_root` option say "Use the specified SDK root *instead of the SDK containing this tool*". This made me think that, despite being shipped standalone, the tool expects to be part of a bundle where the SDK is installed aswell.

Comment: Just specific a folder to `--sdk_root` works on fedora 29 x86_64 workstation. e.g. `./sdkmanager --version --sdk_root=/home/software/androidsdk`

Comment: still I get error: $ andriod
-bash: andriod: command not found

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share my experience.

At first I try to explain why directory structure has to look
the way shown in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460681/1758733 .
https://stackoverflow.com/users/668455/tristan asked for explanation several times so hope I will clarify
the situtation with the next experiment:

```
1. unpack cmdline-tools to any path, for example c:\Android\tools;
2. create a folder for SDK, let it be c:\Android\SDK;
3. install cmdline-tools (yes, we install cmdline-tools again =)):
    c:\Android\tools\bin\sdkmanager --sdk_root=c:\Android\SDK "cmdline-tools;latest"
4. at this moment we can examine c:\Android\SDK and locate
    the path c:\Android\SDK\cmdline-tools\latest. If we compare
    this folder with the previous version c:\Android\tools we find out
    that they are identical. The new installed c:\Android\SDK\cmdline-tools\latest\sdkmanager works
    without --sdk_root argument so we could initially unpack cmdline-tools
    to cmdline-tools\latest.
```

One may encounter another issue - [Stuck at ".android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433542/stuck-at-android-repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded)

Other issues & facts:

```
1. QtCreator works with another sdkmanager that placed in SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
2. SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager works only with JDK 8
3. Java uses its own storage for certificates and it's not convinient usually.
    Thus one may want to use Windows certificate store. Unfortunately Grandle has the
    issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056537 - so use the following:
    set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
```

To sum up the following recipe for development with Qt can be composed:

```
1. download commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip
2. extract cmdline-tools so there will be hierarchy
    SDKROOT
        - cmdline-tools
            - latest
                - bin
                    - sdkmanager.bat
                    - ...
                - lib
                - ...
3. install JDK 8. set JAVA_HOME=c:\path\to\java so that %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe exists.
4. set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
5. NDK may be downloaded manually or installed with sdkmanager
6. install required components:
    SDKROOT\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager "tools" "build-tools;BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION" "platform-tools" "platforms;ANDROID_VERSION"
7. run qtcreator from console so JAVA_OPTS is taken into account (or set it globaly for windows user or even station)
8. tools -> options -> devices set paths to JDK 8, SDKROOT and NDK
```

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK Tools now rest in following location: "**android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/**";

Therefore to solve this problem in **Windows** (same can be replicated in other OS), do the following:

1. Inside your `android_sdk` folder, create the folder: `cmdline-tools` and inside it create another folder: `version` extract / put all your files "/bin /lib NOTICE and sources.properties" files inside this `version` folder.
2. Set `ANDROID_HOME` to your `android_sdk` folder.
3. Add to your System Path: `android_sdk\cmdlineAndroidSDK\cmdline-tools\version\bin\`

Similarly, place your **Android SDK Platform Tools** inside your `android_sdk/platform-tools/` and add corresponding `PATH` to `ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES` under `System Variables`

Comment: No .. its "android_sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/"  ??

Comment: for me "android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/" worked 100% correctly. and it's also mentioned on the android studio website.

Answer (score 2):

Based on updated suggestions from @Jing Li. Here's my version of gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "30"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.2"
  ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS: "6858069"
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - mkdir -p android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - cd android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - unzip android-sdk.zip
  - rm android-sdk.zip
  - mv cmdline-tools version
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | version/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
  - cd ../../
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/
```

Answer (score 1):

This page from Unity 2018 documentation also has a good explanation of resolving this issue, including such points like:

1. Installing the Android SDK without Android Studio.
2. Workaround for “Warning: Could not create settings” and “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException”
3. The trick for Android Studio version 3.6 or newer.
4. Warning about Java 9 or later, a JDK must be version 8.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

Comment: This actually works, all the other answers are very outdated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux and at the same time, you don't want to mess your hands with complex workarounds, I recommend you to download and use [the Snap version of sdkmanager](https://snapcraft.io/androidsdk).

Remember to use `androidsdk` instead of `sdkmanager` in the terminal.

Comment: `sudo snap install androidsdk && androidsdk 'platforms;android-34'`

Answer (score 1):

Since new updates, there are some changes that are not mentioned in the documentation. After unzipping the command line tools package, the top-most directory you'll get is cmdline-tools. Rename the unpacked directory from cmdline-tools to tools, and place it under $C:/Android/cmdline-tools

now it will look like $C:/Android/cmdline-tools/tools

and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The first requirement of installing SDK (Any method) is to install **Java** & setting **JAVA_HOME** path.
Then, SDK command-line tools need installation path without which it throws NullPointerException.
To overcome this just pass the path where you want to install SDK with argument "--sdk_root"
**Eg.** sdkmanager.bat "platform-tools" "platforms;android-" --sdk_root=

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution for Ubuntu using Android Studio**
Here's the working procedure for Ubuntu and Debian like linux :

1. install Android studio as desribed in their website
   https://developer.android.com/studio/install
2. run : `flutter config --android-studio-dir <location of android studio>` then `flutter config --android-sdk /home/user/Android/Sdk` (this is the default location of the SDK)
3. add the bin to your PATH `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/`
4. Afterwards, run : `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all licences
   To check if everything is ok run the doctor in verbos mode as following :   `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

Here is very basic and simple solution
just change the folder structure
change main folder name to latest
then create a folder  named cmdline-tools
create new folder inside cmdline called tools and put bin and other data inside tools folder
so it will look like this
**user\latest\cmdline-tools\tools**

I have searched  alot but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

as of march 7th 2023 , the SDK manager states: Move the original cmdline-tools directory contents, including the lib directory, bin directory, NOTICE.txt file, and source.properties file, into the newly created latest directory. You can now use the command-line tools from this location.

Answer (score -3):

Android Studio is necessary when installing the command line tools even if it's not the editor you use to develop apps with. Unchecking the obsolete packages tab and downloading the tools should do it; that should clear the license issue and you can go back to your favorite IDE (such as VS Code).

Comment: this isn't the answer to my question