# SDKmanager : Warning: Could not create setting. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

Im trying to install androidSDK on my Ubuntu but when i try to run the SDK manager on the tools/bin/sdkmanager folder i get this message:

My Ubuntu was installed recently and still have nothing on it except for Java 8 and Android Studio.

My SDK folder is the default ~/Android/Sdk.

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Usage:
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version

With --install (optional), installs or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.
With --uninstall, uninstall the listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

With --update, all installed packages are updated to the latest version.

With --list, all installed and available packages are printed out.

With --licenses, show and offer the option to accept licenses for all
     available packages that have not already been accepted.

With --version, prints the current version of sdkmanager.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

    --verbose: Enable verbose output.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS. ```
````

Answer (score 24):

After messing around with the console, i think i found out what is happening.
Apparently there's a bug in the way the SDK locates the SDK installation folder.

So all i needed to do way specify it by using **--sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}** after exporting the path with **export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk**

So the full command was **yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --version**

Got the solution from another post: [Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)

Answer (score 11):

Android SDK Tools now rest in following location: "**android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/**";

Therefore to solve this problem in **Windows** (same can be replicated in other OS), do the following:

1. Inside your `android_sdk` folder, create the folder: `cmdline-tools` and inside it create another folder: `version` extract / put all your files "/bin /lib NOTICE and sources.properties" files inside this `version` folder.
2. Set `ANDROID_HOME` to your `android_sdk` folder.
3. Add to your System Path: `android_sdk\cmdlineAndroidSDK\cmdline-tools\version\bin\`

Similarly, place your **Android SDK Platform Tools** inside your `android_sdk/platform-tools/` and add corresponding `PATH` to `ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES` under `System Variables`

Comment: This should be the selected answer for the "settings not found" problem

Answer (score 0):

Using the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line) as guide I was able to make it work moving the installation to the following path in Windows: `%LocalAppData%\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\2.1` for version `2.1`. Similar to what **shahab Uddin** suggested but with `-` instead of `_` in `android-sdk`.

Your version can be checked in the `source.properties` file.