# Error while installing Android SDK Tools 'commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest'

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I have downloaded `commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip` from https://developer.android.com/studio and tried to run this command:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

However its giving this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Testing
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Testing

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

[How to configure Android SDK correctly using commandlinetools in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60735616)

Which directs to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60731814/13317692

Essentially, due to some error present in the current provided download of Android SDK Tools, `commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip`, as of time of this writing (April 15th, 2020), one needs to append `--sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME%` in front of `sdkmanager`, like this:

`sdkmanager --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME% "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"`

That should work.