# avdmanager hangs on "Loading local repository..." Linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, avd-manager

Repro:

1. Headless Ubuntu `18.04 LTS` VM (kvm note enabled)
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install -y wget openjdk-8-jre-headless libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 python3-pip nginx unzip`
4. `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip`
5. `sudo unzip commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip -d /opt`
6. `sudo /opt/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install --sdk_root=/opt "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-19"`
7. `/opt/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n arm -k "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a" -f`

On step 7 in hangs with `Loading local repository...`

Notes:

- Running the avdmanager as `sudo` doesn't help, and the image need's to be created by a user anyway.
- Tried `sudo setfacl -m u:username:rwx /opt/tools/bin/avdmanager` didn't help
- setting `ANDROID_HOME=/opt` and `PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` doesn't help
- newer version of command line tools don't help ether (step 4).

What is the problem? How can I investigate? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened because since version **(6200805)** Command Line Tools should be placed inside **cmdline-tools** directory. It should be created manually in ANDROID_HOME.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176718/7100772).
With the mentioned configuration everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem. I believe there may be something wrong with the `avdmanager` or `sdkmanager` because it always identifies a wrong sdk_root path. For example, if I create a folder under my root on the server (e.g., `/root/SDK`) as the sdk root, the `avdmanager` does not search for folders like `emulator`, `platform-tools`, etc, under `root/SDK`. It turns out it always searches in an upper level folder (i.e., `/root`). If there are many things in the `/root`, the search process will take a lot of time, that's the reason why it hangs on "loading local repository". If you wait enough time, you will eventually see the result. So to word around this, my solution is to put sdk root in one deeper folder level (e.g., `/root/SDK/android_sdk_linux`). The `avdmanager` still starts searching in the upper level folder (i.e., `/root/SDK`), but it's very quick because there is nothing in `/root/SDK`. There can be some warnings output by `avdmanager` but you can ignore them because in my experience there is no side effects.

Comment: This answer saved me from madness.