# Run flutter from vs code to physical phone without Android studio or emulator on windows

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio-code

I started to Learn flutter toolkit need to run the app on physical phone no need to install emulator or Android studio just I install:
A)Flutter sdk and add to windows path.
B)install vs code to use as editor , just add flutter plugin to it

C) connect my physical Android phone and already work in developer mode.

The problem when I run command

Give me that my phone not connect and when run app using F5 in vs code ask for emulator I don't need that I need physical phone only.

That is flutter doctor I have any body can help me what I need to add to my PC no need Android studio no need to add any emulator.

```
$ flutter doctor

[√Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft 
Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158], locale ar-SA)
 [XAndroid toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
  Install Android Studio from: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
  On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android 
SDK components.
  (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for 
detailed instructions).
  If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
  You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!Android Studio (not installed)
[√ VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[!Connected device
No devices available
```

Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must need android sdk to run flutter app on your android and xcode for running on iphone. Download android sdk and check again.

Comment: now solved according to this Question answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se/61150826
must install command tools inside cmdline-tools folder