# Android sdkmanager does not list installed packages?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I have an old installation of "sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip", located right inside my home directory at **`/home/myuser/sdk-tools-linux-4333796`**

I have unzipped the new SDK download in my home directory which creates the folder **`/home/myuser/tools`**.

To make sure that the 2 installations do not interfere with each other I have commented out environment variables from my path and rebooted.

**The problem**: `/home/myuser/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/home/myuser/tools --list` doesn't show my installed packages (I use "--sdk_root" due to a known [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)).

[image]

I'm stuck on this since 2 days and would really appreciate someone at least confirming that behaviour by leaving a comment. I have searched through all related google results but there's absolutely noone reporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot believe it, I found the answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176718/13154227). Thank you so much Jing Li!

So basically what you have to do is put the "tools" folder that you get after unzipping inside a folder named "cmdline-tools" (how on earth would you know... !?). And then later the path to that "cmdline-tools" folder is your "--sdk_root" parameter. Keep in mind that I'm using "--sdk_root" due to a bug at the time (april 2020), hopefully soon all of this is not needed anymore. My installed packages are listed now.