# android studio Command line tools((sdkmanager error))

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Command line tools via the following link, but encounters this error when running sdkmanager:

https://developer.android.com/studio

Where do the bugs come from, because other bats run without bugs.

```
PS C:\Android> sdkmanager --version
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Usage:
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)

Comment: no, i test it but not working.
i  also use this [link](https://android.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-android-sdk-tools-on-windows)