# I am having Issues Installing Android SDK "Could not create settings"?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk

Every time I type this `C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat --list` in my command prompt this message pops up.

I tried all the answers listed in the similar previous questions. I even changed the tools in the **SDK** folder to the tools in the command-line tool. Sometimes the **SDK** manager also gets deleted automatically and I have to paste it again from the command-line tool. Help will be much appreciated.

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug in the latest `sdkmanager`'s configuration handling.
set your environment variables appropriately and i think you'll have to run it as...

```
sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=<path/to/your/sdk/installation> --list
```

try this link, maybe useful to you.
[Android Command line tools sdkmanager always shows: Warning: Could not create settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se)

worked for me on my termux android installation.