# Setup Android SDK for Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, sdk, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, ubuntu-20.04

`appc ti setup check` tells me that Android SDK not found. `appc ti info` suggested to tell Titanium where the Android SDK is located. The Android SDK is intalled in `/usr/lib/android-sdk`. If I try to setup Android SDK, then I run into the following error:

```
$ appc titanium setup android
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.1.1
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Enter ctrl-c at any time to quit.

───────────────────┤ Android Settings ├───────────────────

Path to the Android SDK
Enter "none" if you don't want to build for Android.
: /usr/lib/android-sdk
[ERROR] Invalid Android SDK path
Required file does not exist: "/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/android"
```

I found this issue documented [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium/issues/358). I tried to follow the solution under section "manual way":

1. install cmdline-tools, how to do it properly is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se).
2. then I used sdkmanager to update packages as it mentioned.

   ```
   /usr/lib/android-sdk
    ├── build-tools
    │   ├── 27.0.1 -> debian
    │   └── debian
    │       └── lib
    ├── cmdline-tools
    │   └── tools
    │       ├── bin
    │       └── lib
    ├── extras
    │   └── android
    │       └── m2repository
    ├── licenses
    ├── platforms
    │   ├── android-23
    │   └── android-29
    │       ├── data
    │       ├── optional
    │       ├── skins
    │       └── templates
    ├── platform-tools
    │   ├── api
    │   ├── lib64
    │   └── systrace
    │       └── catapult
    └── tools
        ├── bin
        └── proguard
            ├── bin
            └── lib
   ```

But the issue still exists. Can someone please explain me what this issue is about exactly?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes I did. I reinstalled the android sdk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstall my android sdk:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove android-sdk libcanberra-gtk-module
$ sudo rm -r /opt/adroid-sdk
```

Download cmdline-tools from https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools and install it:

```
$ mkdir /opt/adroid-sdk
$ mkdir /opt/adroid-sdk/cmdline-tools
$ sudo unzip commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip
$ sudo mv cmdline-tools /opt/adroid-sdk/cmdline-tools/6858069
```

Setting my environment variables `nano ~/.bashrc` and after I refresh `source ~/.bashrc`:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/6858069/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
```

Then I installed sdk packages

- Android SDK tools
- Android SDK Platfom-tools
- Android SDK Build tools (29.0.3)
- Android 10.0 (API 29) SDK Platform
- other APIs

  ```
  $ sudo env "PATH=$PATH" sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository" "system-images;android-29;default;x86_64" "build-tools;29.0.3" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"
  ```

Once installed you can create simulators via the CLI.

```
$ appc ti setup check
Android Environment
  ✓  sdk                installed (/opt/android-sdk)
  ✓  tools              installed (v26.1.1)
  ✓  platform tools     installed (v30.0.5)
  ✓  build tools        installed (v29.0.3)
  ✓  adb                installed /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
  ✕  android            "android" executable not found; please reinstall
```

Comment: Fix your typos.