# Setting Android Development command line tools: Error: Could not determine SDK root

Tags: android, react-native

so I am trying to setup android development environment for working with React Native.

Now I have done then following:

1. Downloaded the command line tools zip file from Android Studio.
2. Extracted the zip file into `/opt/android`
3. opened my `nano .bash_profile` added the following below

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android export
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator export
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools export
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin export 
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Edit**
I just now saw this thread: [Having similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se) but when I tried to change the `$ANDROID_HOME` to `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`  as suggested from that thread I still get the same error as before so I do not know where I am missing it

4. Loaded the config to shell `source .bash_profile`
5. So I tried to run the following `sudo /opt/android/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --list` I get the following error below:

```
Error: Could not determine SDK root.
Error: Either specify it explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected location: <sdk>/cmdline-tools/latest
```

**So from there I get stuck because I would not know what  Android studio packages am I to install can I please get some assistance really stuck**