# Gradle, You have not accepted license agreements (Android SDK)

Tags: android, gradle

Yes, I know there are dozens of posts on this subject but nothing I've tried is working.

I'm doing this running Gradle from the command line, not from Android Studio, and on Windows.

I've just deleted my previous Android SDK folder downloaded the latest Android SDK, and installed to C:\android-sdk

Ran:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "build-tools;28.0.3"    "platforms;android-26" "platforms;android-28"
```

then ran:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

and accepted every license,
with it's response:  All SDK package licenses accepted

Then I run:

```
C:\Dev>SET ANDROID_HOME=C:/android-sdk&&SET PATH=C:/gradle-4.0/bin;%PATH%&&SET JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31&&cd C:/Android/dev/ProgramName&&gradle clean
```

And get this error:

```
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3, Android SDK Platform 28].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
```

ANDROID_HOME is set to the SDK directory.
I've tried building with different Gradle versions.
Deleting the licenses directory and re-running 'sdkmanager --licenses'

Most of the existing "solutions" are several years old
and many are for Linux command lines.

Since this seems to be happening from a Gradle build are there any Gradle options that might help?

I do have more than one Android SDK installed,
another one in C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows,
but ANDROID_HOME is set to the SDK directory
I'm trying to use.

I've had this issue before and was able to resolve it, but I can't remember what I did, and it seems to be with the newer platforms;android-28.

UPDATE:

One reason this is important is that the Play Store will require
apps to have a target API of 28 by August, which is why I was
trying to do this build.

Just tried this, did --uninstall on "build-tools;28.0.3" and "platforms;android-28", leaving only platforms;android-26,
and installed "build-tools;28.0.2", re-did sdkmanager --licenses
and now it only gets the error:

```
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.2].
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on linux with android command-line tools, downloaded from here https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools.
I unzipped the archive and created a folder named "latest" inside it. Then I moved all the contents of the archive into the "latest" folder.

After that I did:

```
./cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

and accepted them all. Then a folder was created: "./licenses"

What worked for me was copying the "./licenses" folder to "cmdline-tools/latest/bin/". After that everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept the license agreements.

1. Locate SDK Manager at **$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin**.
2. Run the sdkmanager: **sdkmanager --licenses** on Windows, **./sdkmanager --licenses** on Linux.
3. Accept the licenses you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I followed the advice given in the question about sdkmanager commands and added what the compiler said was missing.

In my /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses directory there was only one file, called "apache-2.0".

I found some more files in /opt/android-sdk/licenses.

I copied them all to /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses.

It got rid of these error messages.