# Flutter doctor issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to fun flutter doctor to fix some issues but get stuck with the below line.

```
$flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):        
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en-DE)

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...⣻
```

I tried to install the certificates but when using

```
$flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

I get stuck at

```
[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...
```

Comment: I think you can try to accept all licenses manually. Here is how:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences/41978530

Comment: Are you using any company provided network? If yes then disable firewall and allow android studio to use network with local admin rights

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues with "[flutter doctor](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli)," here are some common steps to troubleshoot:

Check Flutter Installation
Update Flutter
Check Dart SDK
Android Studio/VS Code Integration
Xcode Installation (for macOS)
Search for Solutions