# Cannot build an Android Studio project on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, apple-m1

I just bought a Mac Pro M1 and downloaded Android Studio. When I try to build my project I get this build error

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
```

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with M1. I've seen that on Intel Mac as well. It's something to do with your project setup.

Comment: Yes you are right. That was a project issue. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you are trying to build your project on a new machine, make sure you have [accepted all software licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences) for Android SDK components, which Gradle might be installing automatically if you haven't already installed them (and thus manually accepted the licenses).