# "License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted"

Tags: android, installation, sdk

I just installed Android Studio on a new device and during my first project I get this error:

> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.

Please, what should I do?

Answer (score 12):

In Android Studio:

- Go to `Tools` -> `SDK Manager`
  [image: Tools > SDK Manager]
- Select `Android SDK` and then the `SDK Tools` tab
- Mark the `Google Play Licensing Library` and click on `OK` to install it
  [image: Android SDK - SDK Tools - Google Play Licensing Library]

Now your error should be all gone, if not, restart your Android Studio.

Comment: I did the same thing in intellij and that worked for me as well!

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly same error on Windows 10 but above solution didn't work for me. As this error was specially pointing towards 30.0.2, I checked in Android Studio under Tools>>SDK Manager>> SDK Platforms and found that only latest Android 12.0(S) with API level 31 was installed. I checked Android 11.0(R) to install API level 30 and error got resolved.
[Screenshot for solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm3VI.png)

Answer (score 2):

For Linux

Go to `Android\sdk\tools\bin`

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

For MacOS

```
yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

For Windows

```
cmd.exe /C"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses"
```

Make sure that Java is installed before hand

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782695/9722336) answer

Comment: I am running this in my circleci environment and not works, any  idea?