# Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 'My Application' error - solved

Tags: android

When I run the Empty Activity 'My Application', I get the following error message:

Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2

### Please advise what to do to solve this issue.

This had nothing to do with accepting licenses for sdk30 since i was using sdk31 only.
Compile sdk version and Build tools version were not set in the created project. When I select version 31 for both the problem got solved

[File>Project Structure>Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSrOx.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences

Comment: I would recommend that you always research before posting a new question over here, I'm also voting to flag this as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)

Comment: This had nothing to do with accepting licenses for sdk30 since i was using sdk31 only. Compile sdk version and Build tools version were not set in the created project. When I select version 31 for both the problem got solved

File>Project Structure>Modules