# Error "License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 not accepted."

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio on a Mac laptop that runs Apple Silicon.

Android Studio installed the SDK and java version for me.

When I open an Android Project I get the error...

```
    License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 not accepted.
```

When I try to run `sdkmanager --licenses` I get the error...

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `and why does Android Studio ship in a broken state?` i doubt anyone will (ever) be able to answer that

Comment: i'm guessing you've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372165/4729721) ?