# Löve android distribution and licence

Tags: android, love2d

I can't compile a minimalist Löve project in order to make an app for Android. I'm stuck at the "licence stage". In **Debian 10**, **sdkmanager** seems not to be installable separately (all sources I found on the internet mention or suppose some Android SDK program previously installed). I haven't found any independent executable or installer to it. I do not want to install Android SDK in order to create a licence. Since this is my first time creating an Android app, I would like to know how to insert such a licence "manually".

Command as per [this tutorial](https://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution#Android)

`./gradlew assembleEmbedNoRecordRelease`

Error:

```
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring project ':love'. 
> com.android.builder.sdk.LicenceNotAcceptedException: Failed to install
> the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using a tag. The `distribution` tag is not what you assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you have not accepted license for Android SDK, which is required, if you want to use it (compile Android app). You need to accept this license. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences) how to automatically accept all Android SDK licenses.

`sdkmanager` is part of Android Studio, but it is also included in [Command line tools only](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-line-tools-only) package, which is much lighter.

Comment: Even after accepting licenses, the compiling process accuses the same issue. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding `--sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to the `sdkmanager` command-line and be sure it is same as you set before `./gradlew assembleEmbedNoRecordRelease`

Comment: I've already done in this. Peheaps some data that could be updated (changed) only by root.... I don't know

Comment: I done this while ago, but I know, root was not required. I managed to accept the licenses thru `sdkmanager` somehow, but it took me like days to figure it out and I forgot what I have done... Maybe try to remove all sdks and install them thru sdkmanager, not thru gradle (required versions are mentioned in GitHub love-android repo).