# Android SDK Manager keeps auto-selecting system images

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I was wondering if there is some way to prevent Android's SDK Manager from auto-selecting a whole bunch of system images every time it starts. It's the one thing it doesn't seem to be able to remember.

Btw, the reason I don't want the system images is that they take up a lot of space and my C: drive has limited space (128GB SSD).

It's kind of frustrating to me that I have to uncheck ~10 items from the list every time there is an update for something I do have installed.

Comment: Hmm this looks promising. You can use the android sdk manager from commandline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation?rq=1 I'll have to look into it and cherry pick from this to get the answer to my question but it may be a solution :D