# How to install a large number of android-sdk tools and automatically accept their licenses?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to automate the process of installing some Android SDK tools through a Gradle script.

The idea is to run this build.gradle script within a Docker machine which will prepare the environment before issuing the main build itself.

The problem I'm having is with automatically accepting the licenses for the relevant packages i'm installing.

Following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681697/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-android-sdk-installation/4682241#4682241), I'm trying to use this method:

```
echo "y" | android update sdk -u -a -t 2,4,56,57,58
```

If I run it in terminal it works for up to 6 packages in one command but if I want to install more packages than that, for example:

```
echo "y" | android update sdk -u -a -t 2,6,7,4,30,153,160,161,167,54,53,63,56,57,58,59
```

Then the command fails:

```
Do you accept the license 'intel-android-extra-license-3626590a' [y/n]:
Unknown response ''.
Do you accept the license 'intel-android-extra-license-3626590a' [y/n]:
Unknown response ''.
Max number of retries exceeded. Rejecting 'intel-android-extra-license-3626590a'
Package Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 24, revision 6 not installed due to rejected license 'android-sdk-preview-license-d099d938'.
Package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 1 not installed due to rejected license 'android-sdk-preview-license-d099d938'.
Package ARM 64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 6 not installed due to rejected license 'android-sdk-preview-license-d099d938'.
```

More than that, I need Gradle to run it for me and when I do so, it seems like the output of the first echo (echo "y") is not redirected to the pipe for some reason.

So when I run the relevant Gradle task:

```
12:46:01.178 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
12:46:01.179 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command '/bin/echo'.
12:46:01.183 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
12:46:01.183 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
12:46:01.183 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command '/bin/echo''
12:46:01.184 [QUIET] [system.out] y | /usr/local/bin/android  update  sdk  -u -a -t 2,6,7,4,30,153,160,161,167,54,53,63,56,57,58,59
12:46:01.184 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
12:46:01.185 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/bin/echo'' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
12:46:01.185 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':installSdkBuildTools'
12:46:01.185 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :installSdkBuildTools (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.023 secs.
12:46:01.185 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.023 secs, idle: 0.001 secs
12:46:01.185 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter] Timing: Executing the DAG took 0.044 secs
12:46:01.185 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
12:46:01.186 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The echo command ends successfully with exit status 0 but the packages are not being installed.

I've tried breaking the command to 3 mini commands which will install 6 packages each time but then the `echo "y" | android...` command is not interpreted correctly as mentioned above.

The relevant Gradle task looks like so:

```
task installSdkBuildToolsPart2(type: Exec) {
commandLine '/bin/echo', "y", '|', '/usr/local/bin/android ', 'update ', 'sdk ', '-u -a -t 160,161,167,54,53'
}
```

And I've also tried like that but to no avail:

```
task installSdkBuildToolsPart1(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'bash', '-c'," '/bin/echo', "y", '|', '/usr/local/bin/android ', 'update ', 'sdk ', '-u -a -t 2,6,7,4,30,153'"
}
```

**This is a Gradle question... how should I write the `commandLine` directive in the build.gradle file correctly so that the command is interpreted correctly and the packages are installed and licenses are accepted?**

Anyone knows how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you could take a look at Jake Wharton SDK Manager plugin: https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not use a deprecated plugin.

Comment: Deprecated does not mean it doesn't work. We use on our CI and it works fine.

Comment: Company policy prevents me from using deprecated solutions.

Comment: We use the script from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17863931/650176

Comment: Thanks I've bumped into it already but I will use a simple shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the exec task in Gradle does not know about pipes, so what you have written is simply passing a number of strings to echo; the "y", the pipe "|", the android path, the update command, etc.

One way to do this is to put the command you want to execute that contains pipes or other shell redirections characters into a shell script file, and then have the Gradle task exec that shell script.

Answer (score 0):

We have this command, which works perfectly for us:

```
( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) \
| android update sdk --all -u -t
```

Comment: Anyways I've tried this method with more than 6 packages and it stops the process waiting for me to accept the license