# Compiling Android .apk on Linux Server

Tags: java, android, linux, compiler-construction, ant

I want to be able to build .apk files programmatically given Android projects (folders, .java, .xml, etc files) with ant on my Ubuntu 10.04 i386 Server. I'm not using Eclipse or even a GUI.

1) I have already followed these instructions: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

2) I downloaded/unpacked the Android Linux SDK here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

3) Now when I navigate to `/home/myusername/www/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools` and type in `./android` I get this error:

```
myusername@myserver:~/www/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools$ ./android
Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager
No command line parameters provided, launching UI.
See 'android --help' for operations from the command line.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showMainWindow(Main.java:297)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:281)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:99)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:88)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: what version of java is on your path?   java -version  ?  is JAVA_HOME set to anything in your env?

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux

Comment: @slund when running `java -version` it says "1.5.0_22" even though I apt-get installed 1.6. how should I fix this?

Comment: @Aleadam looks very similar, thanks! sorry i didnt find this before...my apologies

Comment: @lollercoaser no worries. I did not flag it as dupe since it's the same error, but different circumstances. I just linked it to you. Did it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the ./android binary without arguments it tries to open a GUI window.

From the output you presented, it seems that the ./android binary is working great, but since you are running a headless server it crashes.

Here are the command-line steps to build an Android .apk:

1. `android create project --name ExampleProj --activity ExampleProj --path ./ --package com.example.project --target 2`
2. `ant debug`

This will create an *ExampleProj-debug.apk*.

A great source of help is the **--help** argument of the ./android binary, combined with the action you want to take. For instance:

```
android --help create project
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting to run headless android issue some command line options, like **--help**.

However, if this is not your intention and you want to use your display to show android GUI use `ssh -X` to enable X11 forwarding, install `libswt-gtk-3.5-java` and set `ANDROID_SWT` to `/usr/lib/java`.

Comment: oh i see. so when I ssh into my server, I can enable GUI functionality with the -X flag. cool.

Comment: how do I set ANDROID_SWT though?

Comment: Isn't your aim just to build .apks? Enabling X11 forwarding only makes sense if you want to play with the emulator.

Comment: ANDROID_SWT should be set in your environment.

Comment: @nunaxe, yes my aim is solely to build apps. I could care less about the emulator

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dtmilano I managed to find a solution. First, if not installed, install libswt-gtk-3.5-java if on debian machine, swt if on archlinux. If on a i686 machine, enter in terminal:

```
export ANDROID_SWT=path-to-android-sdk/tools/lib/x86
```

If on a x86_64 (you may need some extra 32bit libraries, I dunno)

```
export ANDROID_SWT=path-to-android-sdk/tools/lib/x86_64
```

Then android will run. If you want to make this permanent, one simple way is to put the above line to your ~/.bashrc. After login/logout the change will be permanent :)

Answer (score 0):

Also - my apologies, I dug a little deeper and found a very similar thread here:
["android update sdk" on headless linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux)