# Running aapt on a remote Linux server

Tags: android, linux, centos, centos5, aapt

OK, this might sound a little crazy but here goes:

I have a few hundred Android APK files sitting on a remote (dedicated) server running CentOS 5. I need to grab some meta data off these apk files - specifically: the package name and the permission matrix.

I planned on hacking together a script that would iterate through each .apk file and feeding them to the `aapt` utility

```
aapt dump badging app.apk
```

.. and grabbing the output and parsing it for what I need. Works fine on Windows (I have the SDK installed)

I downloaded the platform SDK for Linux and extracted it but I could not find the `aapt` utility - does this need to be downloaded separately? I'm not sure if I have to actually download the platform files like I did when I installed it on Windows - this is a headless remote server I'm accessing via SSH.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If not, what else could I do to grab the meta data I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking under `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$SDK/tools/` (i.e. `android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-3/tools`).

Comment: Did that already - that directory is empty. I guess I have to download the platform - the question is how? As I said, I have only SSH connectivity to this server.

Comment: Have you actually downloaded the relevant SDK Platform under AVD? You'll need to do this in order to access platform specific tools such as aapt.

Comment: No.. I'm trying to.. `android` keeps failing to start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux/2509760#2509760 - might have to download the platform manually by the looks of it to get the tools

Answer (score 0):

you need to run

```
./android update sdk -u
```

granted that's the lazy/long way but you'll end up with aapt in the platform-tools directory. The -u option is for disabling the gui so it runs in command line.