# Can't launch SDK manager in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, sdk

I am new in Ubuntu and its hard to adapt here. I Have downloaded ADT Bundle from developer.android.com. But can't launch SDK manager.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or swt-!win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:346)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I saw many solution for Windows(Running `SDK manager.exe` or smth), but I'm not able apply it for Ubuntu.

In beginning this dialog box appears

[image]

Comment: Go to this link and follow the step:

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/4682241/3296571

Comment: This will be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux

Comment: @Ludger it says `android: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This wil solve your problem :** 
Open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK is installed, then execute './android sdk'; as they said at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Beside I strongly recommend to install and work on [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) instead of Eclipse ADT if you want to develop on Android.